# Python equivalent to java.util.SortedSet?

Tags: python, data-structures

Does anybody know if Python has an equivalent to Java's SortedSet interface?

Heres what I'm looking for: lets say I have an object of type `foo`, and I know how to compare two objects of type `foo` to see whether `foo1` is "greater than" or "less than" `foo2`. I want a way of storing many objects of type `foo` in a list `L`, so that whenever I traverse the list `L`, I get the objects in order, according to the comparison method I define.

#### Edit:

I guess I can use a dictionary or a list and `sort()` it every time I modify it, but is this the best way?

Comment: good point. by best i mean "most efficient"

Comment: Python's sort is amazingly efficient.  You'll have to compare it against a set and a sorted list.

Comment: Basically no. You need to bring your own tree. If you are only traversing the list once you can use a heapq as described in the answers.

Comment: A recipe that builds on the `bisect` module: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577197-sortedcollection/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Take a look at [BTrees](http://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=btree). It look like you need one of them. As far as I understood you need structure that will support relatively cheap insertion of element into storage structure and cheap sorting operation (or even lack of it). BTrees offers that.

I've experience with ZODB.BTrees, and they scale to thousands and millions of elements.

Comment: This is the proper implementation.

Answer (score 12):

You can use `insort` from the [`bisect`](http://docs.python.org/library/bisect.html#module-bisect) module to insert new elements efficiently in an already sorted list:

```
from bisect import insort

items = [1,5,7,9]
insort(items, 3)
insort(items, 10)

print items # -> [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 10]
```

Note that this does not directly correspond to `SortedSet`, because it uses a list. If you insert the same item more than once you will have duplicates in the list.

Comment: Finally somebody suggests an O(log n) implementation. ;)

Comment: Combine it with an O(log n) binary search (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/212358/binary-search-in-python) to make sure there are no duplicates.

Comment: Actually, it's O(n) for insertion - insertion in a vector requires shifting the elements after the insert point.  It is still O(log(n)) for lookup however, and sorted iteration is just O(n) (vs O(n*log(n)) for dict).

Comment: I did forget about that, but still: Python lists are amortized, so the average insert is O(n)/n, which approaches O(1).

Comment: No - that only covers appending to the end.  Overallocation won't help with inserting the middle: you'll still always have to copy an average of N/2 items one space right completely independent of having to allocate space for the new element.

Comment: O(n) insertion is inefficient compared to binary search tree

Comment: `bisect.insort()` will have O(log**2 n) performance if [blist](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/blist) is used instead of python's standard list data type.

Answer (score 5):

Similar to blist.sortedlist, the [sortedcontainers](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/) module provides a sorted list, sorted set, and sorted dict data type. It uses a modified B-tree in the underlying implementation and is faster than blist in most cases.

The sortedcontainers module is pure-Python so installation is easy:

```
pip install sortedcontainers
```

Then for example:

```
from sortedcontainers import SortedList, SortedDict, SortedSet
help(SortedList)
```

The sortedcontainers module has 100% coverage testing and hours of stress. There's a pretty comprehensive [performance comparison](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/performance.html) that lists most of the options you'd consider for this.

Answer (score 4):

If you're looking for an implementation of an efficient container type for Python implemented using something like a balanced search tree (A Red-Black tree for example) then it's not part of the standard library.

I was able to find this, though:

http://www.brpreiss.com/books/opus7/

The source code is available here:

http://www.brpreiss.com/books/opus7/public/Opus7-1.0.tar.gz

I don't know how the source code is licensed, and I haven't used it myself, but it would be a good place to start looking if you're not interested in rolling your own container classes.

There's [PyAVL](http://linux.softpedia.com/get/Programming/Libraries/pyavl-43893.shtml) which is a C module implementing an AVL tree.

Also, [this thread](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2007-September/628938.html) might be useful to you. It contains a lot of suggestions on how to use the bisect module to enhance the existing Python dictionary to do what you're asking.

Of course, using insort() that way would be pretty expensive for insertion and deletion, so consider it carefully for your application. Implementing an appropriate data structure would probably be a better approach.

In any case, to understand whether you should keep the data structure sorted or sort it when you iterate over it you'll have to know whether you intend to insert a lot or iterate a lot. Keeping the data structure sorted makes sense if you modify its content relatively infrequently but iterate over it a lot. Conversely, if you insert and delete members all the time but iterate over the collection relatively infrequently, sorting the collection of keys before iterating will be faster. There is no one correct approach.

Answer (score 3):

If you only need the keys, and no associated value, Python offers sets:

```
s = set(a_list)

for k in sorted(s):
    print k
```

However, you'll be sorting the set each time you do this.
If that is too much overhead you may want to look at [HeapQueues](http://docs.python.org/library/heapq.html). They may not be as elegant and "Pythonic" but maybe they suit your needs.

Answer (score 2):

Use `blist.sortedlist` from the [blist package](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/blist/).

```
from blist import sortedlist

z = sortedlist([2, 3, 5, 7, 11])
z.add(6)
z.add(3)
z.add(10)

print z
```

This will output:

```
sortedlist([2, 3, 3, 5, 6, 7, 10, 11])
```

The resulting object can be used just like a python list.

```
>>> len(z)
8
>>> [2 * x for x in z]
[4, 6, 6, 10, 12, 14, 20, 22]
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the possibility of using Jython? I just mention it because using TreeMap, TreeSet, etc. is trivial.  Also if you're coming from a Java background and you want to head in a Pythonic direction Jython is wonderful for making the transition easier.  Though I recognise that use of TreeSet in this case would not be part of such a "transition".

For Jython superusers I have a question myself: the blist package can't be imported because it uses a C file which must be imported. But would there be any advantage of using blist instead of TreeSet? Can we generally assume the JVM uses algorithms which are essentially as good as those of CPython stuff?