# Performance filtering within a list

Tags: c++, performance, list, optimization

I have this piece of code which shall perform quite badly the more items get into `m_songs` i'm looking for some optimization in this. The inner forloop is the culprit here since `m_songs` grows over time as the forloop is looping over all items to check if some item is available in the cache.. How would i rewrite this more efficient?

```
for(auto& const filename : filenames) {
    auto alreadyInCache = false;
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < m_songs.size(); i++) {
        if(filename == m_songs[i]->filename) {
            alreadyInCache = true;
        }
    }
    if(alreadyInCache) {
        continue;
    } else {
        // add items to m_songs;
    }
}

// Overwrite our cache with the latest m_songs
```

Alright i've updated my code to use `find_if()`

within the forloop of the filenames i'm now doing this:

```
auto it = std::find_if(m_songs.begin(), m_songs.end(), [filename](std::shared_ptr<Song> n) {
    return n->filename == filename;
});
auto alreadyInCache = it != m_songs.end();

if(alreadyInCache) continue;
```

will this be more efficient and can it be improved even more?

Comment: Have you considered using a `set`/`map`/`unordered_set`/`unordered_map`?

Comment: @NathanOliver i have not since i'm quite unfamiliar with c++ Thanks i'll look into it!

Comment: @NathanOliver underwater it was a vector containing shared pointers of a custom class. I've updated my question with my attempt at `find_if()`, can there be anything more improved?

Comment: If you can use unique pointers. But I fear you need an advanced string compare function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `m_songs` is a sorted `vector`, which I assume it is as it looks like that same code is filling it (`// add items to m_songs`), then you can perform a [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) using [`std::lower_bound`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) instead of checking element by element.

If you were not adding the elements in order already, here's how to do it: [how do you insert the value in a sorted vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15843525/how-do-you-insert-the-value-in-a-sorted-vector)