# how to find the median of a vector if the method is const?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, constants, median

**I've created a method called Collect that adds a bunch of values to a vector** (shown below)

```
void Median::Collect(double datum)
{
  myVector.push_back(datum);
}
```

**I need to create a method that calculates the median of all of the values I collected in the vector in the method above. The function definition is written below**

```
/* Calculates the median of the data (datum) from the Collect method.
 */
 double Median::Calculate() const
{

}
```

So I know that I first need to sort the vector in order to find the median. Below is my attempt:

```
    double Median::Calculate() const
  {
    std::sort(myVector.begin(), myVector.end());
    double median;
    if (myVector.size() % 2 == 0)
    {// even
        median = (myVector[myVector.size() / 2 - 1] + myVector[myVector.size() / 2]) / 2;
    }
    else
    {// odd
        median = myVector[myVector.size() / 2];
    }
    return median;
  }
```

But I realized that this wasn't compiling because the method is const, so sorting the values of the vector would alter the vector, which isn't allowed in a const function. So what am I supposed to be doing for this method?

Comment: *So I know that I need to sort the vector in order to find the median* -- You don't need to call `std::sort`.  Use [std::nth_element (see example)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/nth_element)

Comment: Depending on what exactly the functional requirements for your program are, you could consider moving your sort to your Collect() method so your vector is always sorted. Also you may want to take a look at this answer:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15843525/how-do-you-insert-the-value-in-a-sorted-vector

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie  It's faster but `std::nth_element` still changes the vector. Probably the simple approach would be to copy the vector locally and use `nth_element` on that to return the median. No state change and `const` is enforced.

Comment: I believe this is a homework assignment problem. Just a while ago, there was a similar question relating to finding the `mean` posted by OP. That question was answered by a user and discussed in comments. After a day, the question was totally modified to calculate the median and then subsequently deleted. Now a new question has been posted which is exactly the same as the modified question. I recommend asking separate questions and not deleting original posts. Thank you!

Comment: If median is only occasionally called, you could make a copy of the vector and sort or quick select the copy (note - quick select has worst case time of O(n^2)).

Comment: @MukulGupta it is a homework assignment problem, I've posted all the threads as such. I figured out how to do the collect and calculate method for the mean but for some reason, when I tried to edit my question to adjust to my new problems, it wasn't going through, so I just deleted the whole question and made a new one. I appreciate the advice though, even if it doesn't pertain to the question I was asking haha

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Make a copy of `myVector`, sort it and then calculate the median of that.

We can do a little better than just using `std::sort`. We don't need to sort the vector completely in order to find the median. We can use [`std::nth_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/nth_element) to find the middle element. Since the median of a vector with an even number of elements is the average of the middle two, we need to do a little more work to find the other middle element in that case. `std::nth_element` ensures that all elements preceding the middle are less than the middle. It doesn't guarantee their order beyond that so we need to use [`std::max_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element) to find the largest element preceding the middle element.

Another thing that you may not have considered is the case where `myVector` is empty. Finding the median of an empty vector doesn't really make any sense. For this example, I just used an `assert` but you might want to throw an exception or something.

```
double Median::calculate() const {
  assert(!myVector.empty());
  std::vector<double> myVectorCopy = myVector;
  const auto middleItr = myVectorCopy.begin() + myVectorCopy.size() / 2;
  std::nth_element(myVectorCopy.begin(), middleItr, myVectorCopy.end());
  if (myVectorCopy.size() % 2 == 0) {
    const auto leftMiddleItr = std::max_element(myVectorCopy.begin(), middleItr);
    return (*leftMiddleItr + *middleItr) / 2.0;
  } else {
    return *middleItr;
  }
}
```

Another option is to use a different container to ensure that elements are always sorted. You might consider using [`std::set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set). When you insert into an `std::set`, the set remains sorted so don't have to use `std::sort`, `std::nth_element` or `std::max_element` to find the median. You would get the middle element.

Comment: @JeJo I think the OP just accepted the first answer they saw and then left

Comment: @Kerndog73 this answer actually makes a lot more sense to me than the mutable one haha. I accepted the first answer that “unbroke” my code because i was on a deadline but I really appreciate the thoroughness of your answer + explanation and understand why it would be better programming practice

Answer (score -2):

A `const` method is a method that can be called only on `const` instances of the class it belongs to.  So, if you have declared a class `Median` and you declare a `const` method on it, then *it can only be called with `const` instances of the `Median` class*. There's no possibility to affect a different class, like `std::vector` with that.

Anyway, in case you decide to derive a new class from `std::vector` and consider adding to it a method `median` to calculate the median, you *had better to declare it `const`*. The reason for this is that you don't need to modify the array to get it's median (see below).

In the case you need to sort the array, then you can make a copy, or even better, consider using an array of pointers to the array elements, then sort that array instead, based on the values of the pointed to values, and then consider the central element of that array.  In this way, you are not touching the original instance and can still maintain the `const` attribute for the method.

Answer (score -3):

You could declare your `myVector` as `mutable`. This will allow for the data to change in it, even if you are in a `const` function.

If, for some reason, that is not an option, you can consider using some datatype that keeps your data sorted and inserts new data in a correct position. Then you will not need to sort it each time you run this function, but you will slow down inserts. Consider what is going to happen more often: inserts or getting the median.

---

A harder approach would be to have the best of both worlds. Your vector would remain unchanged, and the second run of the same function would actually return the answer faster than the first.

You can then do the following:

```
// Median.hpp
class Median
{
  std::vector<double> myVector;
  mutable double median;
  mutable bool medianCalculated;
// the rest is the same
};

// Median.cpp
double Median::calculate() const
{
  if(!medianCalculated)
  {
    std::vector<double> copyVector = myVector;
    std::sort(copyVector.begin(), copyVector.end();
    const auto m1 = copyVector.begin() + (copyVector.size() / 2);
    const auto m2 = copyVector.begin() + ((copyVector.size() + 1) / 2);
    median = (*m1 + m2) / 2; // m1==m2 for even sized vector m1+1==m2 for odd sized
    medianCalculated=true;
  }
  return median;  
}
void Median::Collect(double datum)
{
  myVector.push_back(datum);
  medianCalculated=false;
}
```

Comment: Since this is for a school assignment having a mutable vector is probably fine. However this probably isn't the best solution since as someone using this function I would expect calculating the median to leave it's ordering unchanged. Best solution is to copy or if the median function will be called very often some other tricks

Comment: Ugh.. I think this answer might lead to the conclusion of "Hmm, if I have a problem with a const method, just make the members mutable to make it compile."  There are other answers that solve the problem better, without breaking constness.

Comment: @MitchelPaulin since this is an assignment for someone learning, using mutable to break constness is a bad thing to learn. I'm with Andre Kostur here. `mutable` should be use to handle "logical" constness when "bitwise" constness cannot be guaranteed. [here](http://www.highprogrammer.com/alan/rants/mutable.html) a good explanation IMHO

Comment: @MitchelPaulin Interesting, i guess we have different expectations. I would expect for the second calculation of a median on the same dataset to produce a faster result. I guess i will update an answer to show a better solution.

Comment: Oh man, why declare a method `const` just to circunvent that condition and modify it ????  That seriously violates the `const`  attribute and should be considered a programming error in **all cases**.

Comment: @LuisColorado That is blatantly not what is happening here. The method `const` implies that it is actually not changing the data, not that it is not using any memory. You are confusing `const` and `constexpr`.

Comment: Nope, I think we are both saying the same thing indeed.  if the method says `const` then the instance to which it should be applied must be `const`... if you try to make it `volatile` to allow backgroun modifying through a different non-`const` reference, you are violating the `const` contract.  This is what I try to express.  But think that you are dealing with a nonexperienced user, that claims he is a beginner.  A mutable vector is something that you are not allowed to change, but changes... by other means.  Don't think I'm confusing `const` and `constexpr`.  You are prejudging me.

Comment: @LuisColorado `const` means that the concept of data (i.e. the numbers added) does not change, `constexpr` means that there's no change of state. You are still confusing the two, even though you say you don't. There is no change in median calculation if you change the ordering of a vector, thus it is perfectly allowed to be a done.

Comment: @v010dya, I'm not using those concepts at all... I'm using the concept of attaching the reserved word `const` to a method, which has two purposes: The first, and most important is to allow the method to be called for `const` instances (and I don't use `constexpr` in my discurse at all), and the second is to forbid the programmer to modify any of the instance fields, in accordance with the contract acquired for the method to be qualified as `const`.  Please, try to tell me wher in my speech I've used the term `constexpr`, because the only place is to say that I don't use that term at all.

Comment: @v010dya, if you change the order of the elements of a vector, _you are modifying that vector_.... You cannot change the order of the elements of an ordered list (of any kind) without changing it.  Should I change the latitude of a point in the earth with the height?  You indeed make a copy of the vector in your code, to preserve the ordering of the instance.  So what are you trying to say?  I've never talked about `constexrp`s so why are you so embarrassed with me?

Comment: @LuisColorado You have a great ability to respond to a message without reading it. Congrats, it will take you far on the internet. You are still confusing `const` with `constexpr`, the fact that you haven't said it shows me that you probably are unaware of it and insist on using `const` as a catch-all term. `const` unlike `constexpr` is allowed to change the state of an application, and modifying memory is exactly what it can do. And no, `const` is not there only to allow to be called on a `const` object.

Comment: And you have the great ability of knowing me better than I.  You are welcome!!!! :)

Comment: @LuisColorado and v010dya I appreciate y'all's effort to help me but I would appreciate it even more if you would stop beefing over const methods in the stack overflow comments lmao

Comment: @Sarah, I agree completely.  Thanks for the point!  But I have also answered the question.