# Sorted insertion

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to do an ordered insertion in a vector, but the compiler keeps giving me errors.

What I'm trying to do is based here:

[how do you insert the value in a sorted vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15843525/how-do-you-insert-the-value-in-a-sorted-vector/15843629#15843629)

I've run a code like this:

```
#include <utility>

// TIMESTAMP is more complex than this, but just for simplicity...
typedef TIMESTAMP double

int main() {

  const std::vector<std::pair<TIMESTAMP, double>> myVec;
  std::pair<TIMESTAMP, double> pairdata = std::make_pair(4, 4);

  /* adds some ORDERED values here... */
  /* ... */

  /* Tries to insert a new ordered value with 4,4  */

  auto upper =
  std::upper_bound(myVec.begin(), myVec.end(), pairdata,

            [](const std::pair<TIMESTAMP, double> &a, const std::pair<TIMESTAMP, double> &b) -> bool {
                return a.first < b.first;
            }
        );

  myVec.insert(upper, pairdata);

  /** DO MORE STUFF **/

  return 0;

}
```

But I keep getting:

```
error: cannot bind rvalue reference of type ‘std::vector<std::pair<TIMESTAMP, double> >::value_type&& {aka std::pair<TIMESTAMP, double>&&}’ to lvalue of type ‘std::pair<TIMESTAMP, double>’
     myVec.insert(upper, pairdata);
```

What an I doing wrong? I also tried to std::move pairdata, without success:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘std::vector<std::pair<TIMESTAMP, double> >::insert(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const std::pair<TIMESTAMP, double>*, std::vector<std::pair<TIMESTAMP, double> > >&, std::remove_reference<std::pair<TIMESTAMP, double>&>::type) const’
     myVec.insert(upper, std::move(pairdata));
```

And I also tried to use insert_sorted, as given on mentioned link:

```
template<typename T>
typename std::vector<T>::iterator insert_sorted( std::vector<T> &vec, T const& item, std::function<bool(const T&, const T&)> pred )
{
    return vec.insert ( 
        std::upper_bound( vec.begin(), vec.end(), item, pred ),
        item 
    );
}

/** calling **/
std::function<bool(const std::pair<TIMESTAMP, double>&, const std::pair<TIMESTAMP, double>&)> f = 
        [](const std::pair<TIMESTAMP, double> &a, const std::pair<TIMESTAMP, double> &b) -> bool {
            return a.first < b.first;
        };

    insert_sorted(
        myVec, pairdata, f);
```

@EDIT
On my original post, I did not have "const" on myVec. That's was actually my problem. In my code "myVec" was a const reference, so I could not insert on it. My problem is solved :)

Comment: I [can't reproduce](https://godbolt.org/z/voPs1P) your error when including the correct header files.

Comment: Btw, why are you adding a more relaxed comparator than the built-in for `std::pair`? Just add `operator<` to your more complex `TIMESTAMP` and let the default `std::pair<>::operator<` do its work. You should aim for this: `auto upper = std::upper_bound(myVec.begin(), myVec.end(), pairdata);` [example](https://godbolt.org/z/cjhfs7)

Comment: Sorry Ted, you are totally right, this code is not reproducing my error (for some reason). I'm editing to create a more complex example. Sorry, my bad.

Comment: That happens :-) Include the more complex timestamp if you are able to reproduce the error. If you look at my example above (using `std::tie`), perhaps you can avoid some common pitfalls (like making a comparator not fulfilling the strict weak ordering requirement).

Comment: Sometimes, you can discover your problem just by making an example on Stackoverflow.
My problem was actually that "myVec" was passed as a const reference on a method, so I could not insert on it.

I used  a lambda here only because I thought that it would be needed. But I removed it and it continues working.

I'm editing the original post just to model what my real problem was.

So... thanks for your help :)