# Efficient way to insert data into a sorted vector

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, c++20

Having a sorted `std::vector`, inserting an element in order can be done using this code.

After inserting a single element I require the vector to be sorted for processing.

```cpp
template< typename T >
typename std::vector<T>::iterator 
   insert_sorted( std::vector<T> & vec, T const& item )
{
    return vec.insert
        ( 
            std::upper_bound( vec.begin(), vec.end(), item ),
            item 
        );
}
```

This code is not very efficient compared to a call to `emplace_back`.

Is there a best implementation to insert data in a sorted vector maybe using std::rotate to avoid data reallocation/transition

NB I'm not comparing the two insertion but just to have an idea from a nominal case (i.e. inserting ordered numbers)

Comment: you're comparing a binary search followed by an insert to an append. vectors are famously bad at inserting or removing elements in the middle.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how do you insert the value in a sorted vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15843525/how-do-you-insert-the-value-in-a-sorted-vector)

Comment: Question suffers from [XY problem](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). There is no faster way to insert items into a vector. Simply inserting item in the middle of vector has `O(n)` time complexity (n - size of vector). Proper way to fix your problem is redesign algorithm or data structure, but question do not have information about that.

Comment: You have to understand your data and what operations you need most. And then you select (or design) a datastructure to match. So explain a bit more about the size of your data, how often you're going to add data, do you expect data locality is important (caches/contigous memory) etc.  Side note : It might even be faster to insert items at the back and then call sort O(log n). Specifically if you're going to insert values in batches.

Comment: If insertion performance is critical then you'll need to use a different data structure like `std::set` but you'll need to benchmark your application to ensure that it doesn't end up being more expensive elsewhere

Comment: Yes I did the test and std::vector is more efficient than std::set

Comment: Again you are asking wrong question. You should describe problem where you are using this sorted vector.

Comment: You will only know by doing tests on each method, but I do not see why an append and rotate would be faster than an insert, given that the rotate moves more data. You can avoid a reallocation if you know before hand how large your vector will grow and pre-allocating it

Comment: "Yes I did the test and std::vector is more efficient than std::set" this depends on the size of the container. For small sizes the vector is expected to be fast, but there is a turning point after which inserting into the `std::set` is faster.

Comment: Naturally, the approach you show is less efficient than `emplace_back()`  ....  because `emplace_back()` does not ensure the vector is sorted when done.   So your claim is comparing an apple with an orange.   To make the comparison with `emplace_back()` fairer, you need to sort the vector after  e.g. `vec.emplace_back(item); std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());`

Comment: its an interesting question, but the optimal solution depends on so many factors, size of the input, usage patterns (how many inserts vs how many read accesses), that a proper answer isnt just some code and stating "this is optimal"

Comment: as you accepted the answer, I suppose your usage pattern is many inserts, not so many reads. If thats the case, you could mention that in the question.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai, I have process the vector just after insertion (vector must be sorted before processing)

Comment: you mean, after inserting a single element you require the vector to be sorted? Please clarify that in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you showed does a different thing to `emplace_back`, it isn't meaningful to compare their runtimes.

The code you show is required to be at least asymptotically optimal for inserting one arbitrary value.

If you have another use case, you can do something else.

For instance if you expect most elements to be inserted at the back, you can just test that case first, and insert at the end.

```
template< typename T >
typename std::vector<T>::iterator 
   insert_sorted_expect_greatest( std::vector<T> & vec, T const& item )
{
    typename std::vector<T>::iterator where = item > vec.back() ? vec.end() : std::upper_bound( vec.begin(), vec.end(), item );

    return vec.insert( where, item );
}
```

Comment: I amended the question. NB I'm not comparing the two insertion but just to have an idea from a nominal case (i.e. inserting ordered numbers)

Comment: @TedZach what operation do you actually want?

Comment: I need to insert while keeping ordering. 90% the new element is greater than the last inserted one

Comment: Execuse me. All inserted elements

Comment: @greater than the last inserted one or greater than all the elements? Are you inserting one at a time, or can you insert a range?

Comment: I'm inserting one element at a time. And process the vector after insertion

Comment: Then you don't need to *insert* into a sorted vector. You can insert into a vector and sort later.

Comment: So insert with binary search is worst than emplace_back + sort ?

Comment: @TedZach for some number of insertions

Comment: Why not if in order [[likely]] emplace_back else emplace_back + sort ?

Comment: Oh, I have misread the requirement. If you need to process `vec` after each insertion, then emplace_back + sort is probably worse than search + insert. But for your actual data you might not see much difference

Comment: I will try it using quickbench to see the result

Answer (score 6):

You can get almost as good using amortised analysis. What you do is have an encompassing data structure that holds a vector. You push_back or emplace_back into the vector and pretend it was a sorted insert while it is not. You record internally that there are new (unsorted) entries.

Then the next time someone accesses the data, *then* you sort the entire thing. `std::sort` is really good on contiguous data. If you have a lot of sorted inserts before the next access, this works really well. Both analytically as well as in practice.

Comment: This answer is good assuming that he inserts multiple items and after that he need it to be sorted. If he after each insert of single item he needs to use sorted range, then his method is better, but still bad. So basically your answer add adds some assumption to a question.

Comment: @MarekR Which would probably be why I stated outright what the caveat and explicit assumption is? Do you think that is not clear enough?