# Python list giving different order

Tags: python

why is the order different in the below.

Edit:

Also what is the correct solution for this,i.e, remove duplicates and preserve order

```
def rt(s):
  s = list(s)
  print s
  print set(s)

print rt('abc')
```

Output

```
['a', 'b', 'c']
set(['a', 'c', 'b'])
None
```

Comment: Sets do not have any sense of order.

Comment: What sort of solution are you looking for? Do you want to have an ordered set?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you remove duplicates from a list in Python whilst preserving order?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/480214/how-do-you-remove-duplicates-from-a-list-in-python-whilst-preserving-order)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def unique(sequence):
    seen = set()
    for e in sequence:
        if e not in seen:
            seen.add(e)
            yield e
```

Usage:

```
>>> ''.join(unique('aaabbddeffg'))
'abdefg'
```

See the [`itertools` recipes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes) for a slightly more efficient version, called `unique_everseen`.

Answer (score 3):

Because `set` isn't an ordered structures. Internally, a `set` uses a hash table, and there is no restriction that the hashed function maintain the ordering of its arguments.

Comment: @Rajeev A solution requires a problem. What is the problem? After your edit, the question is quite unclear.

Comment: @Rajeev Is the input list always sorted?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [OrderedSet](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ordered-set), which serves your purpose.

[Documentation](http://orderedset.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

```
pip install orderedset


from orderedset import OrderedSet

def rt(s):
    s = list(s)
    print s
    print OrderedSet(s)

print rt('abc')
```

Comment: The most correct answer is the most downvoted too :)

Comment: Agreed. But the function would be more useful if it returned something.

Comment: @juanchopanza I wrote the same function user asked the question with, it was just to withdraw analogy

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a set with preserved order, you can look here for various solutions:
[Why are there no containers sorted by insertion order in Python's standard libraries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5953205/sorted-container-in-python)

If you want to eliminate the duplicates, and sort it you can use:

```
s = sorted(set(s))
```

From most inner call:

`set` - removes duplicates

`sorted` - sorts it in ascending order.

Also, you're missing a return statement, thus last print is `None`

Comment: The two calls to `list` are totally unnecessary. BTW, it appears that the OP wants to preserve order, not sort the elements.

Comment: Thanks for noticing. Edited in case OP finds it helpful.