# lambda versus list comprehension performance

Tags: python, algorithm, lambda, set, list-comprehension

I recently posted a question using a lambda function and in a reply someone had mentioned lambda is going out of favor, to use list comprehensions instead. I am relatively new to Python. I ran a simple test:

```
import time

S=[x for x in range(1000000)]
T=[y**2 for y in range(300)]
#
#
time1 = time.time()
N=[x for x in S for y in T if x==y]
time2 = time.time()
print 'time diff [x for x in S for y in T if x==y]=', time2-time1
#print N
#
#
time1 = time.time()
N=filter(lambda x:x in S,T)
time2 = time.time()
print 'time diff filter(lambda x:x in S,T)=', time2-time1
#print N
#
#
#http://snipt.net/voyeg3r/python-intersect-lists/
time1 = time.time()
N = [val for val in S if val in T]
time2 = time.time()
print 'time diff [val for val in S if val in T]=', time2-time1
#print N
#
#
time1 = time.time()
N= list(set(S) & set(T))
time2 = time.time()
print 'time diff list(set(S) & set(T))=', time2-time1
#print N  #the results will be unordered as compared to the other ways!!!
#
#
time1 = time.time()
N=[]
for x in S:
    for y in T:
        if x==y:
            N.append(x)
time2 = time.time()
print 'time diff using traditional for loop', time2-time1
#print N
```

They all print the same N so I commented that print stmt out (except the last way it's unordered), but the resulting time differences were interesting over repeated tests as seen in this one example:

```
time diff [x for x in S for y in T if x==y]= 54.875
time diff filter(lambda x:x in S,T)= 0.391000032425
time diff [val for val in S if val in T]= 12.6089999676
time diff list(set(S) & set(T))= 0.125
time diff using traditional for loop 54.7970001698
```

So while I find list comprehensions on the whole easier to read, there seems to be some performance issues at least in this example.

So, two questions:

1. Why is lambda etc being pushed aside?
2. For the list comprehension ways, is there a more efficient implementation and how would you KNOW it's more efficient without testing? I mean, lambda/map/filter was supposed to be less efficient because of the extra function calls, but it seems to be MORE efficient.

Paul

Comment: Added fifth way of attacking this: traditional for loops. :-)

Comment: Consider using xrange in preference to range when you're iterating like this - xrange creates an iterable sequence which is evaluated lazily, while range makes an entire list beforehand

Comment: You're better off not adding a bunch of unrelated timings, since you're just going to distract people from what you're really asking.

Comment: Thanks Stephen!

Glenn, the timings are integral to the question I am asking in regards to efficiency of operations. Several people have pointed out a better way to do the timing, however. Thanks for your comment!

Comment: This question doesn't make any sense as asked; `lambda` and list comprehensions do completely unrelated things. The actual comparison is with `filter`.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Your tests are doing very different things. With S being 1M elements and T being 300:

```
[x for x in S for y in T if x==y]= 54.875
```

This option does 300M equality comparisons.

```
filter(lambda x:x in S,T)= 0.391000032425
```

This option does 300 linear searches through S.

```
[val for val in S if val in T]= 12.6089999676
```

This option does 1M linear searches through T.

```
list(set(S) & set(T))= 0.125
```

This option does two set constructions and one set intersection.

---

The differences in performance between these options is much more related to the algorithms each one is using, *rather* than any difference between list comprehensions and `lambda`.

Comment: Ah, good point. Order(?) type stuff. Where would be the best place to read up on the O() calcs of these types of operations?

Comment: The O of the first 3 cases is the same - O(n*m)=O(m*n) however some of them are doing more work in Python and others are doing more work n C.

Comment: As it turns out, all of those (except the last one) are doing 300000000 "operations". From a theoretical perspective, they could be considered the same. The differences come more from a computer engineering than a computer science perspective: They have to do more with the choices you've made in the way you look through each list. Experimentation and a good grounding in what each expression is actually doing will be most helpful here.

Answer (score 25):

When I fix your code so that the list comprehension and the call to `filter` are actually doing the same work things change a whole lot:

```
import time

S=[x for x in range(1000000)]
T=[y**2 for y in range(300)]
#
#
time1 = time.time()
N=[x for x in T if x in S]
time2 = time.time()
print 'time diff [x for x in T if x in S]=', time2-time1
#print N
#
#
time1 = time.time()
N=filter(lambda x:x in S,T)
time2 = time.time()
print 'time diff filter(lambda x:x in S,T)=', time2-time1
#print N
```

Then the output is more like:

```
time diff [x for x in T if x in S]= 0.414485931396
time diff filter(lambda x:x in S,T)= 0.466315984726
```

So the list comprehension has a time that's generally pretty close to and usually less than the lambda expression.

The reason lambda expressions are being phased out is that many people think they are a lot less readable than list comprehensions.  I sort of reluctantly agree.

Comment: Thanks for the "N=[x for x in T if x in S]" re-write, and for the timing. Makes sense!

Comment: "I sort of reluctantly disagree."??? I definitely whole-heartedly unquestionably disagree.

Answer (score 20):

Q: Why is lambda etc being pushed aside?

A: List comprehensions and generator expressions are generally considered to be a nice mix of power and readability.  The pure functional-programming style where you use `map()`, `reduce()`, and `filter()` with functions (often `lambda` functions) is considered not as clear.  Also, Python has added built-in functions that nicely handle all the major uses for `reduce()`.

Suppose you wanted to sum a list.  Here are two ways of doing it.

```
lst = range(10)
print reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, lst)

print sum(lst)
```

Sign me up as a fan of `sum()` and not a fan of `reduce()` to solve this problem.  Here's another, similar problem:

```
lst = range(10)
print reduce(lambda x, y: bool(x or y), lst)

print any(lst)
```

Not only is the `any()` solution easier to understand, but it's also much faster; it has short-circuit evaluation, such that it will stop evaluating as soon as it has found any true value.  The `reduce()` has to crank through the entire list.  This performance difference would be stark if the list was a million items long, and the first item evaluated true.  By the way, `any()` was added in Python 2.5; if you don't have it, here is a version for older versions of Python:

```
def any(iterable):
    for x in iterable:
        if x:
            return True
    return False
```

Suppose you wanted to make a list of squares of even numbers from some list.

```
lst = range(10)
print map(lambda x: x**2, filter(lambda x: x % 2 == 0, lst))

print [x**2 for x in lst if x % 2 == 0]
```

Now suppose you wanted to sum that list of squares.

```
lst = range(10)
print sum(map(lambda x: x**2, filter(lambda x: x % 2 == 0, lst)))

# list comprehension version of the above
print sum([x**2 for x in lst if x % 2 == 0])

# generator expression version; note the lack of '[' and ']'
print sum(x**2 for x in lst if x % 2 == 0)
```

The generator expression actually just returns an iterable object.  `sum()` takes the iterable and pulls values from it, one by one, summing as it goes, until all the values are consumed.  This is the most efficient way you can solve this problem in Python.  In contrast, the `map()` solution, and the equivalent solution with a list comprehension inside the call to `sum()`, must first build a list; this list is then passed to `sum()`, used once, and discarded.  The time to build the list and then delete it again is just wasted.  (EDIT: and note that the version with both `map` and `filter` must build *two* lists, one built by `filter` and one built by `map`; *both* lists are discarded.)  (EDIT: But in Python 3.0 and newer, map() and filter() are now both "lazy" and produce an iterator instead of a list; so this point is less true than it used to be.  Also, in Python 2.x you were able to use itertools.imap() and itertools.ifilter() for iterator-based map and filter.  But I continue to prefer the generator expression solutions over any map/filter solutions.)

By composing `map()`, `filter()`, and `reduce()` in combination with `lambda` functions, you can do many powerful things.  But Python has idiomatic ways to solve the same problems which are simultaneously better performing and easier to read and understand.

Comment: Steve, thanks! I learned a lot from this simple example and from your great teaching. It's going to be interesting to learn the best and most efficient ways of doing things in Python. It reminds me somewhat of APL in it's constructs, and I think trying to 'master' Python might be a good thing for to spend time doing.

Answer (score 8):

Many people have already pointed out that you're comparing apples with oranges, etc, etc.  But I think nobody's shown how to a really simple comparison -- list comprehension vs map plus lambda with little else to get in the way -- and that might be:

```
$ python -mtimeit -s'L=range(1000)' 'map(lambda x: x+1, L)'
1000 loops, best of 3: 328 usec per loop
$ python -mtimeit -s'L=range(1000)' '[x+1 for x in L]'
10000 loops, best of 3: 129 usec per loop
```

Here, you can see very sharply the cost of lambda -- about 200 microseconds, which in the case of a sufficiently simple operation such as this one swamps the operation itself.

Numbers are very similar with filter of course, since the problem is **not** filter or map, but rather the lambda itself:

```
$ python -mtimeit -s'L=range(1000)' '[x for x in L if not x%7]'
10000 loops, best of 3: 162 usec per loop
$ python -mtimeit -s'L=range(1000)' 'filter(lambda x: not x%7, L)'
1000 loops, best of 3: 334 usec per loop
```

No doubt the fact that lambda can be less clear, or its weird connection with Sparta (Spartans had a Lambda, for "Lakedaimon", painted on their shields -- this suggests that lambda is pretty dictatorial and bloody;-) have at least as much to do with its slowly falling out of fashion, as its performance costs.  But the latter are quite real.

Comment: Thanks, Alex! That's quite useful!

Answer (score 4):

First of all, test like this:

```
import timeit

S=[x for x in range(10000)]
T=[y**2 for y in range(30)]

print "v1", timeit.Timer('[x for x in S for y in T if x==y]',
             'from __main__ import S,T').timeit(100)
print "v2", timeit.Timer('filter(lambda x:x in S,T)',
             'from __main__ import S,T').timeit(100)
print "v3", timeit.Timer('[val for val in T if val in S]',
             'from __main__ import S,T').timeit(100)
print "v4", timeit.Timer('list(set(S) & set(T))',
             'from __main__ import S,T').timeit(100)
```

And basically you are doing different things each time you test. When you would rewrite the list-comprehension for example as

```
[val for val in T if val in S]
```

performance would be on par with the 'lambda/filter' construct.

Comment: Thanks for the note on timeit, I'll remember that!

Answer (score 2):

Sets are the correct solution for this. However try swapping S and T and see how long it takes!

```
filter(lambda x:x in T,S)

$ python -m timeit -s'S=[x for x in range(1000000)];T=[y**2 for y in range(300)]' 'filter(lambda x:x in S,T)'
10 loops, best of 3: 485 msec per loop
$ python -m timeit -r1 -n1 -s'S=[x for x in range(1000000)];T=[y**2 for y in range(300)]' 'filter(lambda x:x in T,S)'
1 loops, best of 1: 19.6 sec per loop
```

So you see that the order of S and T are quite important

Changing the order of the list comprehension to match the filter gives

```
$ python -m timeit  -s'S=[x for x in range(1000000)];T=[y**2 for y in range(300)]' '[x for x in T if x in S]'
10 loops, best of 3: 441 msec per loop
```

So if fact the list comprehension is slightly faster than the lambda on my computer

Comment: time diff filter(lambda x:x in T,S)= 12.6879999638

Thanks! The light switch got turned on with Greg's post. I think I need to read up on how the operations are performed.

Comment: This doesn't answer his question--he's not asking about sets vs. the others.  He probably shouldn't have confused the question by including them.

Comment: @Glenn, I thought the question was more about when/if lambda is faster than other approaches. I think it's wuite importnat if there are cases where lambda is say 10% faster than the alternatives

Answer (score 1):

Your list comprehension and lambda are doing different things, the list comprehension matching the lambda would be `[val for val in T if val in S]`.

Efficiency isn't the reason why list comprehension are preferred (while they actually are slightly faster in almost all cases). The reason why they are preferred is readability.

Try it with smaller loop body and larger loops, like make T a set, and iterate over S. In that case on my machine the list comprehension is nearly twice as fast.

Answer (score 1):

Your profiling is done wrong. Take a look the [timeit module](http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html#module-timeit) and try again.

`lambda` defines anonymous functions. Their main problem is that many people don't know the whole python library and use them to re-implement functions that are already in the `operator`, `functools` etc module ( and much faster ).

List comprehensions have nothing to do with `lambda`. They are equivalent to the standard `filter` and `map` functions from functional languages. LCs are preferred because they can be used as generators too, not to mention readability.

Comment: Thanks THC4k! I'll spend more time looking into generators!

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty fast:

```
def binary_search(a, x, lo=0, hi=None):
    if hi is None:
        hi = len(a)
    while lo < hi:
        mid = (lo+hi)//2
        midval = a[mid]
        if midval < x:
            lo = mid+1
        elif midval > x: 
            hi = mid
        else:
            return mid
    return -1

time1 = time.time()
N = [x for x in T if binary_search(S, x) >= 0]
time2 = time.time()
print 'time diff binary search=', time2-time1
```

Simply: less comparisions, less time.

Comment: Binary search copy-pasted from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/212358/binary-search-in-python

Comment: Also note that S should be ordered list when using binary search.

Answer (score 0):

List comprehensions can make a bigger difference if you have to process your filtered results. In your case you just build a list, but if you had to do something like this:

```
n = [f(i) for i in S if some_condition(i)]
```

you would gain from LC optimization over this:

```
n = map(f, filter(some_condition(i), S))
```

simply because the latter has to build an intermediate list (or tuple, or string, depending on the nature of S). As a consequence you will also notice a different impact on the memory used by each method, the LC will keep lower.

The lambda in itself does not matter.

Comment: not true in python3 while filter and map are lazy. they do not build an intermediate list anymore, instead, they return an iterator (so you have to turn them into list explicitly)