# What is the most efficient way to the determine items of a list which are greater than a threshold?

Tags: python, list, runtime, list-comprehension

Basically, I am wondering what is **the most efficient method** to find the elements of a python list with a value of greater than, say, n.

I believe, the easiest, yet not so efficient, way is as below,

```
for i in range(len(theList)):
    if theList[i] > n:
        subList.append(theList[i])
```

Moreover, we have the single line `for` as below,

```
(subList for subList in theList if sublist > n)
```

(Please correct me if there is anything wrong with the above syntax)

Finally, we can use `filter()` function, which is not pleasant to use, at least for me.

The above methods were all the ways that I know. If you know any better method please tell me. Otherwise, please explain which one is the best, in the sense of efficiency and **run-time**.

Comment: Why isn't `filter` pleasant to use for you?

Comment: If you are just trying to return a list with only elements where the value is greater than `n`, then your comprehension is a good way to go. If you mean to return a list rather than a generator, you can modify it as `[elem for elem in elems if elem > n]`

Comment: @benvc I am asking about a comparison of run-times. The mentioned question is just pointing out the method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no *always right* answer to this and there have been a few SO posts about the speed of different approaches when handling list, see e.g.  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3013449/list-comprehension-vs-lambda-filter), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247486/list-comprehension-vs-map) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1632902/lambda-versus-list-comprehension-performance).

What is the fastest way might depend a lot on your list.
This said, let's just have a look at how fast the suggested approaches are.

For simple comparisons like this you can use [timeit](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html):

**1. Case: The for-loop**

```
for_case = """newList=[]
for x in theList:
    if x > n:
            newList.append(x)"""
```

**2. Case: List comprehension**

```
list_comp = '[x for x in theList if x > n]'
```

**3. Case: The filter (somehow unliked)**

```
filtering = 'list(filter(lambda x: x > n, theList))'
```

*Some preparation:*

```
import timeit
si = 'theList=range(2000);n=1000;'  # using list(range(2000)) has no effect on the ranking
```

**So let's see:**

```
timeit.timeit(si+list_comp, number=10000)
Out[21]: 1.3985847820003983
timeit.timeit(si+filtering, number=10000)
Out[22]: 3.315784254024038
timeit.timeit(si+for_case, number=10000)
Out[23]: 2.0093530920275953
```

So, at least on my machine, the list comprehension takes it away, followed by the `for`-loop and, at least in this case the unliked `filter` is indeed the slowest.

Comment: Thank you. I believe this is the ultimate answer :)
The only question left to be settled now is if there are any other ways to do so?

Comment: @HosseinRahimi You are welcome. There are a few question about speed here on SO, e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3013449/list-comprehension-vs-lambda-filter), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247486/list-comprehension-vs-map) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1632902/lambda-versus-list-comprehension-performance). All are a good read if you are interested in this subject!

Comment: How this answer is different from the one posted already? is there a need for for loop ? or filter?

Comment: @HosseinRahimi there are certainly other ways, but when it comes to the fastest ones, then those 3 are about it I think.

Answer (score -1):

list comprehension version:

```
sublist = [ i for i in the_list if i > n ]
```

Generator expression: ( if the list is huge size)

```
sublist = ( i for i in the_list if i > n )
```