# How to find a value closest to another value X in a large sorted array efficiently

Tags: python, search

For a sorted list, how can I find the smallest number which close to the a given number?

For example,

```
mysortedList = [37, 72, 235, 645, 715, 767, 847, 905, 908, 960]
```

How can I find the largest element which is less or equal to 700 **quickly**? (If I have 10 million elements, then it will be slow to search linearly). In this example, the answer is 645.

Comment: @cricket_007 Actually, he can do a binary search.

Comment: @cricket_007 I think there is a method, which like binary search. The search begins in the middle...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9706041/finding-index-of-an-item-closest-to-the-value-in-a-list-thats-not-entirely-sort ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find next lower item in a sorted list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591159/find-next-lower-item-in-a-sorted-list)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the [`bisect`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html) module:

```
import bisect

data = [37, 72, 235, 645, 715, 767, 847, 905, 908, 960]

location = bisect.bisect_left(data, 700)

result = data[location - 1]
```

This is a module in the standard library which will use [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) to find the desired result. Depending on the exact value that you need you can also use [`bisect_right`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html#bisect.bisect_right) instead of [`bisect_left`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html#bisect.bisect_left).

This is faster than iterating over the list because the binary search algorithm can skip parts of the data that won't contain the answer. This makes it very suitable for finding the nearest number when the data is known to be sorted.

Comment: This is as fast as it gets, takes O(log n) time.

Answer (score 1):

Manually implemented binary search

```
def find_largest_less_than(l, max_val, lo=0, hi=None):
    if hi is None:
        hi = len(l)

    if lo > hi: return None
    if hi - lo == 1: return None if max_val < l[lo] else l[lo]

    mid = lo + ((hi - lo) // 2)
    mid_val = l[mid]

    if max_val > mid_val:
        val = find_largest_less_than(l, max_val, mid, hi)
    elif max_val < mid_val:
        val = find_largest_less_than(l, max_val, 0, mid)

    return val

mysortedList = [37, 72, 235, 645, 715, 767, 847, 905, 908, 960]
my_max = 700

find_largest_less_than(mysortedList, my_max) # 645
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> lst = [i for i in mysortedList if i <= 700]
>>> lst[-1]
```

Comment: This will trasverse all items in the list, even if it has found the number halfway through. The OP said his list has millions of elements.

Comment: @Reti43 The OP didn't mention millions of elements in his post. I didn't read the comments. My bad!

Comment: No worries. My comment only served to bring this to your attention for this exact reason.

Comment: @Reti43 Thanks! I appreciate it.