# Finding the nearest value and return the index of array in Python

Tags: python, numpy, python-3.x

I found this post: [Python: finding an element in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604802/python-finding-an-element-in-an-array)

and it's about returning the index of an array through matching the values.

On the other hand, what I am thinking of doing is similar but different. I would like to find the nearest value for the target value. For example I am looking for 4.2 but I know in the array there is no 4.2 but I want to return the index of the value 4.1 instead of 4.4.

What would be the fastest way of doing it?

I am thinking of doing it the old way like how I used to do it with Matlab, which is using the array A where I want to get the index from to minus the target value and take the absolute of it, then select the min. Something like this:-

```
[~,idx] = min(abs(A - target))
```

That is Matlab code but I am newbie in Python so I am thinking, is there a fast way of doing it in Python?

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2566412/find-nearest-value-in-numpy-array and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6065697/python-numpy-quickly-find-the-index-in-an-array-closest-to-some-value might be useful.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This is similar to using bisect_left, but it'll allow you to pass in an array of targets

```
def find_closest(A, target):
    #A must be sorted
    idx = A.searchsorted(target)
    idx = np.clip(idx, 1, len(A)-1)
    left = A[idx-1]
    right = A[idx]
    idx -= target - left < right - target
    return idx
```

Some explanation:

First the general case: `idx = A.searchsorted(target)` returns an index for each `target` such that `target` is between `A[index - 1]` and `A[index]`. I call these `left` and `right` so we know that `left < target <= right`. `target - left < right - target` is `True` (or 1) when target is closer to `left` and `False` (or 0) when target is closer to `right`.

Now the special case: when `target` is less than all the elements of `A`, `idx = 0`. `idx = np.clip(idx, 1, len(A)-1)` replaces all values of `idx` < 1 with 1, so `idx=1`. In this case `left = A[0]`, `right = A[1]` and we know that `target <= left <= right`. Therefor we know that `target - left <= 0` and `right - target >= 0` so `target - left < right - target` is `True` unless `target == left == right` and `idx - True = 0`.

There is another special case if `target` is greater than all the elements of `A`, In that case `idx = A.searchsorted(target)` and `np.clip(idx, 1, len(A)-1)`
 replaces `len(A)` with `len(A) - 1` so `idx=len(A) -1` and `target - left < right - target` ends up `False` so idx returns `len(A) -1`. I'll let you work though the logic on your own.

For example:

```
In [163]: A = np.arange(0, 20.)

In [164]: target = np.array([-2, 100., 2., 2.4, 2.5, 2.6])

In [165]: find_closest(A, target)
Out[165]: array([ 0, 19,  2,  2,  3,  3])
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Bago! I am trying to understand the codes and I am having problems with the `idx -= target - left < right - target` part. I am new to Python so I tested the `target - left < right - target` first and they return a range of `True` and `False`. I use the idx to minus the results and I get a slightly distorted array. For example the original index of 0 turns to -1. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 38):

The corresponding Numpy code is almost the same, except you use [`numpy.argmin`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmin.html#numpy.argmin) to find the minimum index.

```
idx = numpy.argmin(numpy.abs(A - target))
```

Comment: `numpy.searchsorted` is also handy (and more efficient) if the input array is in sorted order.

Comment: OP didn't specify it specifically but I thought I'd point out that if `A = [4.1, 4.4, 5, 4.1]` and `target = 4.2`. This code will only return `idx = 0` not `idx = [0, 3]`. Is the only recourse to loop back through `A` comparing each value to the value at `idx = 0`, to determine if there are others?

Comment: @sgallen: The Matlab code OP posted gives `idx = 1` (Matlab index is 1-based), so I guess the others aren't needed.

Comment: as @JoeKington has already mentioned `searchsorted` is faster if A is sorted, but also it can take an array of targets as it's argument so it is especially useful if you need to repeat this with more than one target. If that would be useful for you let me know and I'll write it up as an answer.

Comment: I use this function to search for a sorted array to be honest. I am would really appreciate it if you can guide me on that, @Bago. Thank you so much! You guys are all really helpful.

Answer (score 9):

Well, more than 2 years have gone by and I have found a very simple implementation from this URL in fact: [Find nearest value in numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2566412/find-nearest-value-in-numpy-array)

The implementation is:

```
def getnearpos(array,value):
    idx = (np.abs(array-value)).argmin()
    return idx
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 5):

Tested and timed two solutions:

```
idx = np.searchsorted(sw, sCut)
```

and

```
idx = np.argmin(np.abs(sw - sCut))
```

for computation in a time expensive method. timing was **113s for computation with the second solution**, and **132s for computation with the first one**.

Comment: Note that these return different results. `np.argmin(np.abs(np.array([1, 2, 3, 4]) - 2.1))` returns 1, where `np.searchsorted([1, 2, 3, 4], 2.1)` returns 2... `np.searchsorted` returns the insertion location to preserve order, thus it returns the index of the first value after the target, which may not be the nearest value. Using any method that minimizes `abs(value-target)` is actually finding the nearest value which may be above or below the target. Either may be appropriate depending on your needs, but they aren't equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

Possible solution:

```
>>> a = [1.0, 3.2, -2.5, -3.1]
>>> i = -1.5
>>> diff = [(abs(i - x),idx) for (idx,x) in enumerate(a)]
>>> diff
[(2.5, 0), (4.7, 1), (1.0, 2), (1.6, 3)]
>>> diff.sort()
>>> diff
[(1.0, 2), (1.6, 3), (2.5, 0), (4.7, 1)]
```

You'll have the index of nearest value in diff[0][1]

Answer (score 0):

```
def finder(myList, target)
    diff = ''
    index = None
    for i,num in enumerate(myList):
        if abs(target - num) < diff:
            diff = abs(target - num)
            index = i
    return index
```

Hope this helps

**EDIT**:

If you'd like a one-liner, then you might like this better:

```
min(L, key=lambda x: abs(target-x))
```