# Matlab to Python conversion: undefined variable

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

I am trying to convert a Matlab program into Python. It's not giving me the results I'd like.

Matlab Code:

```
for jj=1:data_length            %for each symbol in the input symbol sequence

    [a,b]= min(abs(phase_recovered(jj)-U_alphabets));    

    quantized(jj)=U_alphabets(b);     
end
```

Here `quantized` is initialized in the for loop for the first time. However, in Python it was giving the error

> `quantized` is undefined.

So I defined `quantized` as zeros of length equal to `data_length`.

Python Code:

```
quantized=zeros(data_length,dtype='complex')
for jj in arange(0,data_length):
    diff=np.absolute((phase_recovered[jj]-u_alphabets))
    a=diff.argmin()
    b=diff[a]
    quantized[jj]=u_alphabets[b]
```

Comment: You really do want to use better titles for your questions.

Comment: You also need to include what input you are giving this, what output you are expecting and what you got instead.

Comment: *"So I defined `quantized` as zeros of length equal to `data_length`."* Ok, so what's the problem?

Comment: Try a title like, find closest value in an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't want the line `b = diff[a]`, you want something more like:

```
quantized=zeros(data_length,dtype='complex')
for jj in arange(0,data_length):
    diff=np.absolute((phase_recovered[jj]-u_alphabets))
    b = diff.argmin()
    quantized[jj] = u_alphabets[b]
```

Also if u_alphabets happens to be sorted you could use a solution like the one described
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8914491/finding-the-nearest-value-and-return-the-index-of-array-in-python/8929827#8929827).