# find all values close to a target like numpy.searchsorted() but return all same values?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, closest-points

Is there any good ways to find all value indices in an **sorted** array A close to several targets?
Use numpy.searchsorted() can allow us to find indices close to several targets efficiently:
[Finding the nearest value and return the index of array in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8914491/finding-the-nearest-value-and-return-the-index-of-array-in-python)
However, if there are repeated values in array A. This methods will only return 1 of the index rather than all the possible index.
for example an array like this:

```
A = array([    1. ,     2. ,     3. ,     3. ,     3.1,     4. ,    50. ,
          60. ,    70. ,    80. ,    90. ,   100.1,   110. ,   120. ,
         999. ,  1000. ])
targets=[3, 100]
```

it will return idx = [2, 11]
But I would like it to return [[2,3],11]
What I could do is just loop through idx to get boolean indices like [A==A[idx[0]],A==A[idx[1]],...]
But if the targets array is very large, this can be very inefficient.

One thing is I could first find the unique set of the array with numpy.unique(). to find all same values. Then searchsorted() on that unique array, which might save some time. Then I can use this index to find all the same values.

here is an example:

```
def find_closest_multiTargets_inSortred(A,targets):
        #A must be sorted
    idx = A.searchsorted(targets)
    idx = npy.clip(idx, 1, len(A)-1)
    left = A[idx-1]
    right = A[idx]
    idx -= targets - left < right - targets
    return idx

def find_closest_multiTargets_Allrepeats(A,targets):
    ua=npy.unique(A)
    _uaIdxs=find_closest_multiTargets_inSortred(ua, targets)
    return [npy.where(A==ua[_i]) for _i in _uaIdxs]

>>> find_closest_multiTargets_Allrepeats([5.1,5.5,4,1,2.3,5.1,6],[2,5])
[(array([4]),), (array([0, 5]),)]
```

I think, if `len(ua)<<len(A)` it will be far more efficient than try to find the closest directly on A. However, the npy.where step is still looping through the _uaIdxs, if it is large, then it will be very inefficient. If one can build an alternative unique(), to get a indices list for each unique value in A ([[indices have value ua[0]],[indices have value ua[2]]...]). It will be far more efficient:

```
def find_closest_multiTargets_Allrepeats2(A,targets):
    ua,idxList=npy.unique2(A)
    _uaIdxs=find_closest_multiTargets_inSortred(ua, targets)
    return idxList[_uaIdxs]
```

But I do NOT know if there is anything can do what the **unique2()** expected to do. There might be other completely different algorithm can get the same result in a more efficient way other than searchsorted also.

To keep things simple, we assume A is sorted. For unsorted array A, we can always argsort it first.

Is there any one can provide a more efficient way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: What values are you searching for in your example? And how close do you want them?

Comment: @Bas, Thanks, I add the example targets. As closest as possible.

Comment: You also need to define a limit of how close to the target you want them. If the limit is 0.1, I would expect [[2,3,4], 11] in your example], since also 3.1 is 'close' to 3 ...

Comment: @Bas, if you have read the find nearest link, you will find more detail. Closest means, if you have array like [0 0.1 1 10 20 100]. when you want to find value closest to 0, then it is 0. If you want to find value closest to 0.5, then it is 0.1. If you want to find value closet to 90 then it is 100. It has nothing to do with limit.

Comment: [`np.searchsorted`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) has a `side` keyword argument. If you set it to `side='right'`, it will find the last, not the first, index into array at which the search values could be inserted keeping the order. You should be able to find the range of values by calling searchsorted twice, once with `side='left'`, another with `side='right'`.

Comment: @Jaime, yepp, I am aware of this too. But I think do the searchsorted twice on A will be even less efficient than what I proposed.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
a = np.array([1., 2., 3., 3., 3.1, 4., 50., 60., 70., 80., 90., 100.1, 110., 120., 999., 1000.])
t = np.array([3, 100])
```

- calculate the pairwise distance:

  ```
  d = np.abs(np.subtract.outer(a, t))
  ```
- find the closest values:

  ```
  asort = np.argsort(d, axis=0)
  ```
- get the closest indices and the closest values:

  ```
  ind = np.arange(a.shape[0])
  print(ind[asort][0])
  #array([ 2, 11], dtype=int64)

  print(a[asort][0])
  #array([   3. ,  100.1])
  ```

Note that if you use other index `[i]` other than `[0]` in the last step you will get the ith closest value... using `[0]` will result in the closest values.

Comment: see also np.take() and np.unravel_index() which are helpful downstream.

Comment: this is not what we want. U provide a similar solution to `find_closest_multiTargets_inSortred(A,targets)` Only, the efficient may be the same or less than searchsort.

Answer (score 0):

numpy.in1d(A, idx) will do what you appear to wish for.

Comment: in1d() will mix all the values, this is not what we want. If A = [0, 1, 2, 5, 0]. A[idx]=[0,2], it will return [T,F,T,F,T]. but we want [[0,4],2] or [[T,F,F,F,T],[F,T,F,F,F]]