# Return "Iterable" Numbers for Indices in Python Pandas

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

Hi I am really new to Pandas. I tried to figure out what's going on with the datatype here but so far I am unable to go very far.

What I intend to do is very simple indeed. I am searching for the index of a DataFrame `data2` with the nearest time to the target time in `data1`.

Since `data1` and `data2` are very similar, just that there are some minor time difference due to slightly different sampling rate, I attach only the sample of `data1` here:

[image]

I did something like this in the search of closest match data by comparing the timestamp in `data2` to timestamp in `data1`:

```
idxcollect = []
for loopidx, tstamploop in enumerate( tstamp_data1[820990:821000] ):
    idxtemp = data2[ data2['timestamp'] == tstamp_data2.asof(tstamploop) ].index
    delta1 = np.abs( data2.timestamp[idxtemp]     - data1.timestamp[loopidx] )
    delta2 = np.abs( data2.timestamp[idxtemp + 1] - data1.timestamp[loopidx] )

    if delta1.iloc[0] < delta2.iloc[0]:
        idxreturn = idxtemp
        idxcollect.append( idxreturn )
    else:
        idxreturn = idxtemp + 1
        idxcollect.append( idxreturn )
```

`tstamp_data1` / `tstamp_data2` is of `dtype('<M8[ns]')`, calculated from epoch time in `data1` and `data2`.

The output I got is:

`[Int64Index([809498], dtype='int64'), Int64Index([809499], dtype='int64'), Int64Index([809500], dtype='int64'), Int64Index([809501], dtype='int64'), Int64Index([809502], dtype='int64'), Int64Index([809503], dtype='int64'), Int64Index([809509], dtype='int64'), Int64Index([809513], dtype='int64'), Int64Index([809521], dtype='int64'), Int64Index([809533], dtype='int64')]`

What I would like to do is to slice corresponding rows of `data2` from the indices found through the operation above, with something as simple as:

`data2.ix[ idxcollect[:11] ]`

However with the Int64Index format, I am unable to do anything as simple as what I wanted to. Is there any way out? Thank you for your time and attention and help!!

Comment: include some example data. you should only need ~10 rows to demonstrate what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may store the index of data2 as a list, make timestamps of data1 a list and create a new DataFrame for storing the data:

```
data2indx = data2.index.tolist()
data1tm = data1['timestamp'].tolist()
data2sub = pd.DataFrame(columns = data2.columns)
```

Then slice data2 and append row to data2sub based on selection:

```
for n, i in enumerate(data1tm):
    c = [abs(i-j) for j in data2indx]
    mins = min(c)
    index = c.index(mins)
    data2sub.loc[n] = data2.iloc[index]
```

Maybe someone can contribute a more efficient approach.

Comment: Looks kind of promising. Thanks for the prompt reply. Let me try it out and see...

Comment: Your function works perfectly for a small data range. However, it ate up all my 16 Gb of RAM for just a mere processing of 29.6 Mb for data1 and 27.7 Mb of data2...and then the iPython decided to kill the kernel. Is there any way out? Thanks.

Comment: @HarryMacDowel Maybe generated lists are too big so hog system resources. Try the revision.

Comment: Thanks Robbie. Although this is not the most efficient version, at least it does not eat up all the RAMs. The whole execution takes ~60 hours to process a mere 820,000 rows of data. I hope someday maybe someone can think of a better solution. For now, I am very grateful for your commitment to help me to advance forward.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way out to solve the speed problem. The thing is, it takes more time to process *a search for the nearest timestamp* comparing to *a search for the nearest float value*.

So the trick is, if you have already noticed in the data, I already have a `timesec` column.

[image: enter image]

What I did was set the first timestamp as `0` and then from then onwards add the corresponding `timedelta` calculated from the timestamp to the baseline of `0`. This yields the `timesec` column, an easy and fast computation.

In this question, I asked about the "iterable" numbers, and as Robbie has pointed out, the `.tolist()` function will solve the problem of nested list of lists. However, it takes 60 hours to search for a mere 87258 timestamps in another dataset. To speed this up, you can utilize the `timesec` for a cleaner and faster search instead.

By implementing a simple `getnearpos` function [from a previous Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8914491/finding-the-nearest-value-and-return-the-index-of-array-in-python):

```
def getnearpos(array,value):
    idx = (np.abs(array-value)).argmin()
    return idx
```

The search for 87258 timestamps now turns into a search for 87258 float numbers, and the time it takes to finish the search is: 1h 1min 23s, a huge improvement compared to the ~60 hours mark.

If anyone who happens to view this question knows of a faster implementation, do share with me. I am really eager to learn!! Thank you!