# Matching timestamped data to closest time in another dataset. Properly vectorized? Faster way?

Tags: r, match, apply

I have a timestamp in one data frame that I am trying to match to the closest timestamp in a second dataframe, for the purpose of extracting data from the second dataframe. See below for a generic example of my approach:

```
library(lubridate)

data <- data.frame(datetime=ymd_hms(c('2015-04-01 12:23:00 UTC', '2015-04-01 13:49:00 UTC', '2015-04-01 14:06:00 UTC' ,'2015-04-01 14:49:00 UTC')),
                   value=c(1,2,3,4))
reference <- data.frame(datetime=ymd_hms(c('2015-04-01 12:00:00 UTC', '2015-04-01 13:00:00 UTC', '2015-04-01 14:00:00 UTC' ,'2015-04-01 15:00:00 UTC', '2015-04-01 16:00:00 UTC')),
                        refvalue=c(5,6,7,8,9))

data$refvalue <- apply(data, 1, function (x){
  differences <- abs(as.numeric(difftime(ymd_hms(x['datetime']), reference$datetime)))
  mindiff <- min(differences)
  return(reference$refvalue[differences == mindiff])
})

data
#              datetime value refvalue
# 1 2015-04-01 12:23:00     1        5
# 2 2015-04-01 13:49:00     2        7
# 3 2015-04-01 14:06:00     3        7
# 4 2015-04-01 14:49:00     4        8
```

This works fine, except it is very slow, because the reference dataframe is quite large in my real-world application. Is this code properly vectorized? Is there a faster, more elegant way of performing this operation?

Comment: In Python this is exactly what the function numpy.searchsorted is for. I looked for an R equivalent but can't find one so far ..

Comment: @cxrodgers: It would be interesting to see an application of that function to this task. After looking at tis documentation, I'm scratching my head wondering how it would do this. Can you find an SO working example?

Comment: @BondedDust see the answer provided by Bi Rico here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8914491/finding-the-nearest-value-and-return-the-index-of-array-in-python

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can try `data.table`s rolling join using the "nearest" option

```
library(data.table) # v1.9.6+
setDT(reference)[data, refvalue, roll = "nearest", on = "datetime"]
# [1] 5 7 7 8
```

Comment: In one line (without obtaining index): `setDT(data)[, refvalue := setkey(setDT(reference), datetime)[data, refvalue, roll="nearest"]]` - this'll get much nicer when joins with no keys is implemented.

Comment: Is it possible to also add the datetime used from reference and add that to data, for checking how close "nearest" actually is?

Comment: @BetaScoo8 you could do something like `indx <- setkey(setDT(reference), datetime)[data, roll = "nearest", which = TRUE] ; setDT(data)[, c("refdate", "refvalue") := reference[indx]]`

Comment: @BetaScoo8 Btw, you don't need to key anymore, you can now create `indx` using `indx <- setDT(reference)[data, roll = "nearest", which = TRUE, on = "datetime"]` (in v 1.9.6+)

Comment: I initially selected the answer from 42-, but this is the approach I have ended up using on a daily basis. Both work though. data.tables are great for working with large data

Answer (score 19):

I wondered if this would be able to match a data.table solution for speed, but it's a base-R vectorized solution which should outperform your `apply` version. And since it doesn't actually ever calculate a distance, it might actually be faster than the data.table-nearest approach. This adds the length of the midpoints of the intervals to either the lowest possible value or the starting point of the the intervals to create a set of "mid-breaks" and then uses the `findInterval` function to process the times. That creates a suitable index into the rows of the `reference` dataset and the "refvalue" can then be "transferred" to the `data`-object.

```
 data$reefvalue <- reference$refvalue[
                      findInterval( data$datetime, 
                                     c(-Inf, head(reference$datetime,-1))+
                                     c(0, diff(as.numeric(reference$datetime))/2 )) ]
 # values are [1] 5 7 7 8
```