# merge by nearest neighbour in group - R

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have two country*year level datasets that cover the same countries but in different years. I would like to merge the two in a way that year is matched with its nearest neighbor, always within country (iso2code).

The first (dat1) looks like this (showing here only the head for AT, but iso2code has multiple different values):

```
  iso2code  year elect_polar_lrecon
  <chr>    <dbl>              <dbl>
1 AT        1999               2.48
2 AT        2002               4.18
3 AT        2006               3.66
4 AT        2010               3.91
5 AT        2014               4.01
6 AT        2019               3.55
```

The second (dat2) looks like this:

```
  iso2code  year affpol
  <chr>    <dbl>  <dbl>
1 AT        2008   2.47
2 AT        2013   2.49
3 DE        1998   2.63
4 DE        2002   2.83
5 DE        2005   2.89
6 DE        2009   2.09
```

In the end I would like to have something like (note that the value of affpol for 2008 could be matched both with 2010 and with 2006 as it is equally distant from both. If possible, I would go for the most recent date, as it is below):

```
  iso2code  year.1 elect_polar_lrecon year.2 affpol
  <chr>    <dbl>                <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 AT        1999                 2.48  
2 AT        2002                 4.18  
3 AT        2006                 3.66  
4 AT        2010                 3.91  2008    2.47
5 AT        2014                 4.01  2013    2.49
6 AT        2019                 3.55
```

Not sure about how to do this... I am happy for a tidyverse solution, but really, all help is much appreciated!

Comment: Can you show your expected output?

Comment: I did, sorry for not doing it right away.

Comment: Should be straightforward with a rolling join in `data.table`. See e.g. [Matching timestamped data to closest time in another dataset. Properly vectorized? Faster way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31103897/matching-timestamped-data-to-closest-time-in-another-dataset-properly-vectorize/31104160#31104160). Just search the R tag for "data.table roll nearest" for several other nice posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by [Henrik](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68563896/merge-by-nearest-neighbour-in-group-r#comment121172101_68563896), this can be solved by *updating in a rolling join to the nearest* which is available in the [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) package. Additionally, the OP has requested to *go for the most recent date* if matches are equally distant.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat1)[setDT(dat2), roll = "nearest", on = c("iso2code", "year"), 
     `:=`(year.2 = i.year, affpol = i.affpol)]

dat1
```

> ```
>    iso2code year elect_polar_lrecon year.2 affpol
> 1:       AT 1999               2.48     NA     NA
> 2:       AT 2002               4.18     NA     NA
> 3:       AT 2006               3.66   2008   2.47
> 4:       AT 2010               3.91     NA     NA
> 5:       AT 2014               4.01   2013   2.49
> 6:       AT 2019               3.55     NA     NA
> ```

This operation has updated `dat1` by reference, i.e., without copying the whole data object by adding two additional columns.

Now, the OP has requested to *go for the most recent date* if matches are equally distant but the join has picked the older date. Apparently, there is no parameter to control this in a *rolling join to the nearest*.

The workaround is to create a helper variable `nyear` which holds the *negative year* and to join on this:

```
setDT(dat1)[, nyear := -year][setDT(dat2)[, nyear := -year], 
                              roll = "nearest", on = c("iso2code", "nyear"), 
                             `:=`(year.2 = i.year, affpol = i.affpol)][
                               , nyear := NULL]
dat1
```

> ```
>    iso2code year elect_polar_lrecon year.2 affpol
> 1:       AT 1999               2.48     NA     NA
> 2:       AT 2002               4.18     NA     NA
> 3:       AT 2006               3.66     NA     NA
> 4:       AT 2010               3.91   2008   2.47
> 5:       AT 2014               4.01   2013   2.49
> 6:       AT 2019               3.55     NA     NA
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out with the help of a friend. I leave it here in case anyone else is looking for a solution. Assuming that the first dataset is `to_plot` and the second is called `to_plot2`. Then:

```
find_nearest_year <- function(p_year, p_code){

years <- to_plot$year[to_plot$iso2code==p_code] 

nearest_year <- years[1]

for (i in sort(years, decreasing = TRUE)) {
  if (abs(i - p_year) < abs(nearest_year-p_year)) {
    nearest_year <- i
  }
}

return(nearest_year)
  
}

to_plot2 <- to_plot2 %>%
  group_by(iso2code, year) %>%
  mutate(matching_year=find_nearest_year(year, iso2code))

merged <- left_join(to_plot, to_plot2, by=c("iso2code", "year"="matching_year"))
```