# Numpy finding element index in another array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I have an array/set with unique positive integers, i.e.

```
>>> unique = np.unique(np.random.choice(100, 4, replace=False))
```

And an array containing multiple elements sampled from this previous array, such as

```
>>> A = np.random.choice(unique, 100)
```

I want to map the values of the array `A` to the position of which those values occur in `unique`.

So far the best solution I found is through a mapping array:

```
>>> table = np.zeros(unique.max()+1, unique.dtype)
>>> table[unique] = np.arange(unique.size)
```

The above assigns to each element the index on the array, and thus, can be used later to map `A` through advanced indexing:

```
>>> table[A]
array([2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 3, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1,
       3, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 2, 3, 1, 0, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2,
       3, 1, 1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 2, 0, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 0, 1, 3, 0, 2, 0, 1,
       3, 2, 2, 1, 3, 0, 3, 3], dtype=int32)
```

Which already gives me the proper solution. However, if the unique numbers  in `unique` are very sparse and large, this approach implies creating a very large `table` array just to store a few numbers for later mapping.

Is there any better solution?

NOTE: both `A` and `unique` are sample arrays, *not* real arrays. So the question is not how to generate positional indexes, it is just how to efficiently map elements of `A` to indexes in `unique`, the *pseudocode* of what I'd like to speedup in numpy is as follows,

```
B = np.zeros_like(A)
for i in range(A.size):
    B[i] = unique.index(A[i])
```

(assuming `unique` is a list in the above *pseudocode*).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The table approach described in your question is the best option when `unique` if pretty dense, but `unique.searchsorted(A)` should produce the same result and doesn't require `unique` to be dense. `searchsorted` is great with ints, if anyone is trying to do this kind of thing with floats which have precision limitations, consider something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8914491/finding-the-nearest-value-and-return-the-index-of-array-in-python/8929827#8929827).

Comment: And `sorter` could be used with it, if `unique` is not already sorted.

Answer (score 2):

You can use standard python `dict` with `np.vectorize`

```
inds = {e:i for i, e in enumerate(unique)}
B = np.vectorize(inds.get)(A)
```

Comment: Interesting approach, I will have to test the performance of `np.vectorize` for large matrices though.

Comment: np.vectorize loops on the python level, so no need to perform that test... its just syntactic sugar

Answer (score 2):

The [numpy_indexed](https://github.com/EelcoHoogendoorn/Numpy_arraysetops_EP) package (disclaimer: I am its author) contains a vectorized equivalent of list.index, which does not require memory proportional to the max element, but only proportional to the input itself:

```
import numpy_indexed as npi
npi.indices(unique, A)
```

Note that it also works for arbitrary dtypes and dimensions. Also, the array being queried does not need to be unique; the first index encountered will be returned, the same as for list.