# python sample large array using smaller array

Tags: python, arrays

Let's say I have two arrays: SMALL_ARRAY and LARGE_ARRAY
The LARGE_ARRAY contains values that are similar in value (not necessarily the same)
I would like to get a subarray of the LARGE_ARRAY that:

= Has same size as SMALL_ARRAY

= Has similar values (similar distribution) as SMALL_ARRAY

let's assume small = [1,2,3,4] and large = [100,1.8,32,4.1,5,55,34,2.9,1.1,99]

I would like my new array to be [1.1,1.8,2.9,4.1]

so it has same size and similar elements to small

Any assistance please?
Many thanks

Comment: welcome, to stackoverflow! can you post the needed section from your code for better understanding/testing

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "array" (Python has a list of lists and numpy arrays), "similar in value," and "similar distribution."

Comment: let's assume it's a numpy array
let's assume small = [1,2,3,4] and large = [100,1.8,32,4.1,5,55,34,2.9,1.1,99]
I would like my new array to be [1.1,1.8,2.9,4.1]
so it has same size and similar elements to small

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/8914682/3627387

```
LARGE_ARRAY = [100,1.8,32,4.1,5,55,34,2.9,1.1,99]
SMALL_ARRAY = [1,2,3,4]

similar = []
for i in SMALL_ARRAY:
    diff_list = [(abs(i - x), x) for x in LARGE_ARRAY]
    diff_list.sort()
    similar.append(diff_list[0][1])

print(similar)
```

Comment: I think he wants to subsample, but my guess it as good as yours, really....

Comment: @Paul But subsample will look exactly like SMALL_ARRAY

Comment: let's assume small = [1,2,3,4] and large = [100,1.8,32,4.1,5,55,34,2.9,1.1,99]
I would like my new array to be [1.1,1.8,2.9,4.1]
so it has same size and similar elements to small

Comment: @french if this resolves your question. Mark it as answer.

Comment: @SardorbekImomaliev how can I do that?

Comment: @french there is button under arrows on the left side of my answer

Answer (score 0):

`numpy.random.choice` is your friend if you want to subsample uniformly at random:

```
import numpy as np

# 'initialise' small so we know its shape
# obviously you can skip that step if you already know the shape
m, n = 5, 10
small = np.zeros((m, n))

# get a sample from a large array
large = np.random.randn(100,1000)
samples = np.random.choice(large.ravel(), size=m*n)

#  small
small = samples.reshape(small.shape)

print small
```

Comment: let's assume small = [1,2,3,4] and large = [100,1.8,32,4.1,5,55,34,2.9,1.1,99]
I would like my new array to be [1.1,1.8,2.9,4.1]
so it has same size and similar elements to small