# Fastest way to check if a value exists in a list

Tags: python, list, performance, membership

What is the fastest way to check if a value exists in a very large list (with millions of values) and what its index is?

Comment: In python the thing in square brackets is called a list, not an array.  Rather than using a list use a set.  Or keep your list sorted and use the `bisect` module

Comment: So you really need to juggle indices? Or doesn't order actually matter and you just want to do member ship tests, intersections, etc.? In order words, it depends on what you're really trying to do. Sets may work for you, and then they are a really good answer, but we can't tell from the code you showed.

Comment: Probably you have to specify in your question that you need not the value, but its index.

Comment: I edit my question and try to explain more clearly what I want to do ... I hope so...

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: because set cannot contain duplication content, while Jean wants to store location of particles (x,y,z could be the same), we cannot use set in this case

Comment: In an unordered list you must search all items worst case. On average the half of it. If you going to search multiple times, you may benefit from sorting the list once. Also: Did you consider asking at [Blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: One could consider using dictionary instead where the numbers are keys and value 1 means "is in the set" (or any other data you want to link to that number). Accessing data in dictionary is obviously fast when you have the item to search in the key. Do you already have the list at this point, or can you change the data storage format?

Answer (score 2172, accepted):

```
7 in a
```

Clearest and fastest way to do it.

You can also consider using a `set`, but constructing that set from your list may take more time than faster membership testing will save. The only way to be certain is to benchmark well. (this also depends on what operations you require)

Comment: But you don't have the index, and getting it will cost you what you saved.

Comment: like:
If 7 in a:
    b=a.index(7)
?

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: Sets are only an option if you don't need it to be ordered (and hence, have an index). And sets *are* clearly mentioned in the answer, it just *also* gives an straightforward answer to the question as OP asked it. I don't think this is worth -1.

Comment: Okay , I try your method in my real code and it's take a bit more time probably because I need to know the index of the value. With my second method , I check if it exist and get the index at the same time.

Comment: @Jean if you just need the index, by all means use your second method.

Comment: If you have a lot of elements in the list, definitely you should use set instead of list. I tried both, set is much faster.

Comment: How fast *is* this? Relatively speaking, at least?

Answer (score 371):

As stated by others, `in` can be very slow for large lists. Here are some comparisons of the performances for `in`, `set` and `bisect`. Note the time (in second) is in log scale.

[image]

Code for testing:

```
import random
import bisect
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
import time


def method_in(a, b, c):
    start_time = time.time()
    for i, x in enumerate(a):
        if x in b:
            c[i] = 1
    return time.time() - start_time


def method_set_in(a, b, c):
    start_time = time.time()
    s = set(b)
    for i, x in enumerate(a):
        if x in s:
            c[i] = 1
    return time.time() - start_time


def method_bisect(a, b, c):
    start_time = time.time()
    b.sort()
    for i, x in enumerate(a):
        index = bisect.bisect_left(b, x)
        if index < len(a):
            if x == b[index]:
                c[i] = 1
    return time.time() - start_time


def profile():
    time_method_in = []
    time_method_set_in = []
    time_method_bisect = []

    # adjust range down if runtime is too long or up if there are too many zero entries in any of the time_method lists
    Nls = [x for x in range(10000, 30000, 1000)]
    for N in Nls:
        a = [x for x in range(0, N)]
        random.shuffle(a)
        b = [x for x in range(0, N)]
        random.shuffle(b)
        c = [0 for x in range(0, N)]

        time_method_in.append(method_in(a, b, c))
        time_method_set_in.append(method_set_in(a, b, c))
        time_method_bisect.append(method_bisect(a, b, c))

    plt.plot(Nls, time_method_in, marker='o', color='r', linestyle='-', label='in')
    plt.plot(Nls, time_method_set_in, marker='o', color='b', linestyle='-', label='set')
    plt.plot(Nls, time_method_bisect, marker='o', color='g', linestyle='-', label='bisect')
    plt.xlabel('list size', fontsize=18)
    plt.ylabel('log(time)', fontsize=18)
    plt.legend(loc='upper left')
    plt.yscale('log')
    plt.show()


profile()
```

Comment: Love cut-and-paste, executable code like this in answers. To save others a few seconds of time, you'll need 3 imports:
`import random /
import bisect /
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`
and then call:
`profile()`

Comment: always great to get the code but just heads up I had to import time to run

Comment: And don't forget the humble `range()` object. When using `var in [integer list]`, see if a `range()` object can model the same sequence. Very close in performance to a set, but more concise.

Comment: In my experience, converting a large list to set costs more time than searching directly in the list.

Comment: It is probably worth mentioning that this only applies if you are looking for lots of elements in the list - in this code there is one conversion of list to set and then 1000s of membership checks so the faster lookup is more important than the conversion. If you only want to check for a single element @huichen is correct that it will take longer to do the conversion than a single `x in list` check.

Answer (score 73):

You could put your items into a [`set`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset). Set lookups are very efficient.

Try:

```
s = set(a)
if 7 in s:
  # do stuff
```

**edit** In a comment you say that you'd like to get the index of the element. Unfortunately, sets have no notion of element position. An alternative is to pre-sort your list and then use [binary search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/212358/binary-search-in-python) every time you need to find an element.

Comment: And if after that I want to know the index of this value , it's possible and you have a fast way to do it ?

Comment: @Jean-FrancoisGallant: In this case sets won't be of much use. You could pre-sort the list and then use binary search. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Converting to a set for just one lookup is only worth it for very short lists. And there, time doesn't matter anyway.

Answer (score 45):

The original question was:

> What is the fastest way to know if a value exists in a list (a list
>   with millions of values in it) and what its index is?

Thus there are two things to find:

1. is an item in the list, and
2. what is the index (if in the list).

Towards this, I modified @xslittlegrass code to compute indexes in all cases, and added an additional method.

**Results**

[image]

**Methods are:**

1. in--basically if x in b: return b.index(x)
2. try--try/catch on b.index(x) (skips having to check if x in b)
3. set--basically if x in set(b): return b.index(x)
4. bisect--sort b with its index, binary search for x in sorted(b).
   Note mod from @xslittlegrass who returns the index in the sorted b,
   rather than the original b)
5. reverse--form a reverse lookup dictionary d for b; then 
   d[x] provides the index of x.

**Results show that method 5 is the fastest.**

Interestingly the **try** and the **set** methods are equivalent in time.

---

**Test Code**

```
import random
import bisect
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
import timeit
import itertools

def wrapper(func, *args, **kwargs):
    " Use to produced 0 argument function for call it"
    # Reference https://www.pythoncentral.io/time-a-python-function/
    def wrapped():
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapped

def method_in(a,b,c):
    for i,x in enumerate(a):
        if x in b:
            c[i] = b.index(x)
        else:
            c[i] = -1
    return c

def method_try(a,b,c):
    for i, x in enumerate(a):
        try:
            c[i] = b.index(x)
        except ValueError:
            c[i] = -1

def method_set_in(a,b,c):
    s = set(b)
    for i,x in enumerate(a):
        if x in s:
            c[i] = b.index(x)
        else:
            c[i] = -1
    return c

def method_bisect(a,b,c):
    " Finds indexes using bisection "

    # Create a sorted b with its index
    bsorted = sorted([(x, i) for i, x in enumerate(b)], key = lambda t: t[0])

    for i,x in enumerate(a):
        index = bisect.bisect_left(bsorted,(x, ))
        c[i] = -1
        if index < len(a):
            if x == bsorted[index][0]:
                c[i] = bsorted[index][1]  # index in the b array

    return c

def method_reverse_lookup(a, b, c):
    reverse_lookup = {x:i for i, x in enumerate(b)}
    for i, x in enumerate(a):
        c[i] = reverse_lookup.get(x, -1)
    return c

def profile():
    Nls = [x for x in range(1000,20000,1000)]
    number_iterations = 10
    methods = [method_in, method_try, method_set_in, method_bisect, method_reverse_lookup]
    time_methods = [[] for _ in range(len(methods))]

    for N in Nls:
        a = [x for x in range(0,N)]
        random.shuffle(a)
        b = [x for x in range(0,N)]
        random.shuffle(b)
        c = [0 for x in range(0,N)]

        for i, func in enumerate(methods):
            wrapped = wrapper(func, a, b, c)
            time_methods[i].append(math.log(timeit.timeit(wrapped, number=number_iterations)))

    markers = itertools.cycle(('o', '+', '.', '>', '2'))
    colors = itertools.cycle(('r', 'b', 'g', 'y', 'c'))
    labels = itertools.cycle(('in', 'try', 'set', 'bisect', 'reverse'))

    for i in range(len(time_methods)):
        plt.plot(Nls,time_methods[i],marker = next(markers),color=next(colors),linestyle='-',label=next(labels))

    plt.xlabel('list size', fontsize=18)
    plt.ylabel('log(time)', fontsize=18)
    plt.legend(loc = 'upper left')
    plt.show()

profile()
```

Answer (score 34):

```
def check_availability(element, collection: iter):
    return element in collection
```

**Usage**

```
check_availability('a', [1,2,3,4,'a','b','c'])
```

I believe this is the fastest way to know if a chosen value is in an array.

Comment: You need to put the code in a definition: 

    def listValue():
        a = [1,2,3,4,'a','b','c']
        return 'a' in a
    
    x = listValue()
    print(x)

Comment: It's a valid Python answer it's just not good, readable code.

Comment: Beware ! This matches while this is very probably what you did not expect: `o='--skip';  o in ("--skip-ias");   # returns True !`

Comment: @Alex F the `in` operator works the same way to test substring membership. The confusing part here is probably that `("hello")` is not a single-value tuple, while `("hello",)` is -- the comma makes the difference. `o in ("--skip-ias",)` is `False` as expected.

Comment: This one was really usefull to me,but what I have to understand by "collection: iter"

Answer (score 19):

```
a = [4,2,3,1,5,6]

index = dict((y,x) for x,y in enumerate(a))
try:
   a_index = index[7]
except KeyError:
   print "Not found"
else:
   print "found"
```

This will only be a good idea if a doesn't change and thus we can do the dict() part once and then use it repeatedly. If a does change, please provide more detail on what you are doing.

Comment: It's working but not when implemented in my code:
"TypeError: unhashable type:'list'

Comment: @Jean-FrancoisGallant, that's probably because you are using lists where you really ought to be using tuples. If you want comprehensive advice on how to speed up your code, you should post it at codereview.stackexchange.com. There you'll get style and performance advice.

Comment: This is a very clever solution to the problem. Instead of the try except construct, I would do:
    a_index = index.get(7)
which will default to None if the key is not found.

Answer (score 12):

If you only want to check the existence of one element in a list,

```py
7 in list_data
```

is the fastest solution. Note though that

```py
7 in set_data
```

is a near-free operation, independently of the size of the set! Creating a set from a large list is 300 to 400 times slower than `in`, so if you need to check for many elements, creating a set first is faster.

[image]

Plot created with [perfplot](https://github.com/nschloe/perfplot):

```py
import perfplot
import numpy as np


def setup(n):
    data = np.arange(n)
    np.random.shuffle(data)
    return data, set(data)


def list_in(data):
    return 7 in data[0]


def create_set_from_list(data):
    return set(data[0])


def set_in(data):
    return 7 in data[1]


b = perfplot.bench(
    setup=setup,
    kernels=[list_in, set_in, create_set_from_list],
    n_range=[2 ** k for k in range(24)],
    xlabel="len(data)",
    equality_check=None,
)
b.save("out.png")
b.show()
```

Comment: Beautiful fact. Just worth to mention that if that set wont change rapidly and we need to do this check many times may it become reasonable to keep such a `set` IMO AFAIK.

Answer (score 10):

Be aware that the `in` operator tests not only equality (`==`) but also identity (`is`), the `in` logic for `list`s is [roughly equivalent to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43690671/6260170) the following (it's actually written in C and not Python though, at least in CPython):

> ```
> for element in s:
>     if element is target:
>         # fast check for identity implies equality
>         return True
>     if element == target:
>         # slower check for actual equality
>         return True
> return False
> ```

In most circumstances this detail is irrelevant, but in some circumstances it might leave a Python novice surprised, for example, `numpy.NAN` has the unusual property of being [not being equal to itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10034149/why-is-nan-not-equal-to-nan):

```
>>> import numpy
>>> numpy.NAN == numpy.NAN
False
>>> numpy.NAN is numpy.NAN
True
>>> numpy.NAN in [numpy.NAN]
True
```

To distinguish between these unusual cases you could use `any()` like:

```
>>> lst = [numpy.NAN, 1 , 2]
>>> any(element == numpy.NAN for element in lst)
False
>>> any(element is numpy.NAN for element in lst)
True
```

Note the `in` logic for `list`s with `any()` would be:

```
any(element is target or element == target for element in lst)
```

However, I should emphasize that this is an edge case, and for the vast majority of cases the `in` operator is highly optimised and exactly what you want of course (either with a `list` or with a `set`).

Comment: NAN == NAN returning false has nothing unusual about it. It is the behavior defined in the IEEE 754 standard.

Comment: Is this actually true? The following snippet seems to say the opposite:

    (Pdb) 1 in [True, False]
    True
    (Pdb) 1 == True
    True
    (Pdb) 1 is True
    False

Answer (score 8):

It sounds like your application might gain advantage from the use of a Bloom Filter data structure.

In short, a bloom filter look-up can tell you very quickly if a value is DEFINITELY NOT present in a set. Otherwise, you can do a slower look-up to get the index of a value that POSSIBLY MIGHT BE in the list. So if your application tends to get the "not found" result much more often then the "found" result, you might see a speed up by adding a Bloom Filter.

For details, Wikipedia provides a good overview of how Bloom Filters work, and a web search for "python bloom filter library" will provide at least a couple useful implementations.

Answer (score 2):

##### Check if values exist in a list

[xslittlegrass's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40963434/19123103) shows that when checking if multiple values exist in a list, converting the list into a set first and using the `in` operator on the set is much faster than using the `in` operator on lists. On the other hand, [Nico's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68438122/19123103) shows that when checking if a single value exists in a list, converting the list into a set first is not worth it, as converting to a set itself is costly to begin with. Together, these answers imply that there is some number of values where converting to a set and checking if those values exist in the set becomes faster than checking if they exist in the list.

It turns out, that number is very small. The figure below shows the runtime difference between `in` on sets and `in` on lists for different numbers of values to check. As it shows, on average, if you need to check whether 5 (or more) values exist in a list, it's faster to convert that list into a set first and check on the set instead.<sup>1</sup>

[image: result]

---

##### Get their indices if values exist in a list

On the other hand, if you want to check if values exist in a list and return the indices of the values that do, then regardless of the length of the list, for small number of values, directly searching for it using `list.index()` in a try-except block is the fastest way to do it. In particular, if you want to find the index of a single value, this is the fastest option. However, on average, if there are more than 10 values to search for, then constructing an index lookup dictionary (as in [DarrylG's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58844693/19123103)) is the fastest option.<sup>2</sup>

[image: result2]

---

<sup>1</sup> Code used to produce the first figure.

```py
from random import sample
from timeit import repeat
from functools import partial
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator

def list_in(a, b):
    return [x in b for x in a]


def set_in(a, b):
    s = set(b)
    return [x in s for x in a]


def profile(methods):
    sizes = range(1, 31, 2)
    colors = ['r', 'b', 'g']
    Ns = [100, 1000000]
    fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, len(Ns), figsize=(10, 4), facecolor='white')
    for N, ax in zip(Ns, axs):
        b = sample(range(N), k=N)
        times = {f.__name__: [] for f in methods}
        for size in sizes:
            a = sample(range(len(b)*3//2), k=size)
            for label, f in zip(times, methods):
                func = partial(f, a, b)
                times[label].append(min(repeat(func, number=10))/10)
        for (k, ts), c in zip(times.items(), colors):
            ax.plot(sizes, ts, f'{c}o-', label=k)
        ax.set_title(f'List size = {N:,d}', fontsize=18)
        ax.set_xlabel('Number of values to check', fontsize=14)
        ax.set_ylabel('Runtime', fontsize=14)
        ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(5))
        ax.legend()
    return fig


methods = [list_in, set_in]
fig = profile(methods)
fig.tight_layout();
```

<sup>2</sup> Code used to produce the second figure.

```py
def try_index(a, b):
    c = []
    for x in a:
        try:
            c.append(b.index(x))
        except ValueError:
            c.append(-1)
    return c


def set_in(a, b):
    s = set(b)
    return [b.index(x) if x in s else -1 for x in a]


def dict_lookup(a, b):
    # for faster lookups, convert dict to a function beforehand
    reverse_lookup = {x:i for i, x in enumerate(b)}.get
    return [reverse_lookup(x, -1) for x in a]


methods = [try_index, set_in, dict_lookup]
fig = profile(methods)
fig.suptitle('Get index of values that exist in a list', fontsize=20)
fig.tight_layout();
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not the code, but the algorithm for very fast searching.

If your list and the value you are looking for are all numbers, this is pretty straightforward. If strings: look at the bottom:

- -Let "n" be the length of your list
- -Optional step: if you need the index of the element: add a second column to the list with current index of elements (0 to n-1) - see later
- Order your list or a copy of it (.sort())
- Loop through:

  - Compare your number to the n/2th element of the list

    - If larger, loop again between indexes n/2-n
    - If smaller, loop again between indexes 0-n/2
    - If the same: you found it
- Keep narrowing the list until you have found it or only have 2 numbers (below and above the one you are looking for)
- This will find any element in **at most 19 steps for a list of 1.000.000** (log(2)n to be precise)

If you also need the original position of your number, look for it in the second, index column.

If your list is not made of numbers, the method still works and will be fastest, but you may need to define a function which can compare/order strings.

Of course, this needs the investment of the sorted() method, but if you keep reusing the same list for checking, it may be worth it.

Comment: You forgot to mention that the algorithm you explained is a simple Binary Search.

Answer (score 1):

## Edge case for spatial data

There are probably faster algorithms for handling spatial data (e.g. refactoring to use a k-d tree), but the special case of checking if a vector is in an array is useful:

- If you have spatial data (i.e. cartesian coordinates)
- If you have integer masks (i.e. array filtering)

In this case, I was interested in knowing if an (undirected) edge defined by two points was in a collection of (undirected) edges, such that

```
(pair in unique_pairs) | (pair[::-1] in unique_pairs) for pair in pairs
```

where `pair` constitutes two vectors of arbitrary length  (i.e. shape `(2,N)`).

If the distance between these vectors is meaningful, then the test can be expressed by a floating point inequality like

```
test_result = Norm(v1 - v2) < Tol
```

and  "Value exists in List" is simply `any(test_result)`.

Example code and dummy test set generators for integer pairs and R3 vector pairs are below.

```
# 3rd party
import numpy as np
import numpy.linalg as LA
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# optional
try:
    from tqdm import tqdm
except ModuleNotFoundError:
    def tqdm(X, *args, **kwargs):
        return X
    print('tqdm not found. tqdm is a handy progress bar module.')
    

def get_float_r3_pairs(size):
    """ generate dummy vector pairs in R3  (i.e. case of spatial data) """
    coordinates = np.random.random(size=(size, 3))
    pairs = []
    for b in coordinates:
        for a in coordinates:
            pairs.append((a,b))
    pairs = np.asarray(pairs)
    return pairs
    
        
def get_int_pairs(size):
    """ generate dummy integer pairs (i.e. case of array masking) """
    coordinates = np.random.randint(0, size, size)
    pairs = []
    for b in coordinates:
        for a in coordinates:
            pairs.append((a,b))
    pairs = np.asarray(pairs)
    return pairs


def float_tol_pair_in_pairs(pair:np.ndarray, pairs:np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    """
    True if abs(a0 - b0) <= tol & abs(a1 - b1) <= tol for (ai1, aj2), (bi1, bj2)
    in [(a01, a02), ... (aik, ajl)]
    
    NB this is expected to be called in iteration so no sanitization is performed.

    Parameters
    ----------
    pair : np.ndarray
        pair of vectors with shape (2, M)
    pairs : np.ndarray
        collection of vector pairs with shape (N, 2, M)

    Returns
    -------
    np.ndarray
        (pair in pairs) | (pair[::-1] in pairs).
    """
    m1 = np.sum( abs(LA.norm(pairs - pair, axis=2)) <= (1e-03, 1e-03), axis=1 ) == 2
    m2 = np.sum( abs(LA.norm(pairs - pair[::-1], axis=2)) <= (1e-03, 1e-03), axis=1 ) == 2
    return m1 | m2


def get_unique_pairs(pairs:np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    """
    apply float_tol_pair_in_pairs for pair in pairs
    
    Parameters
    ----------
    pairs : np.ndarray
        collection of vector pairs with shape (N, 2, M)

    Returns
    -------
    np.ndarray
        pair if not ((pair in rv) | (pair[::-1] in rv)) for pair in pairs

    """
    pairs = np.asarray(pairs).reshape((len(pairs), 2, -1))
    rv = [pairs[0]]
    for pair in tqdm(pairs[1:], desc='finding unique pairs...'):
        if not any(float_tol_pair_in_pairs(pair, rv)):
            rv.append(pair)
    return np.array(rv)
```

[image: timing results]