# errors in cross checking coordinate values

Tags: list, python-3.x

If I have an (x,y) coordinate e.g. `(1,4)` how can I check if it matches a coordinate in another set of randomly generated coordinates e.g. `[(3,5),(7,3),(6,9),(1,4)]`?

I have tried lots of different ways and keep getting error messages. TIA for any advice.

Comment: What about using the `in` operator? `coordinate in list`...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fastest way to check if a value exist in a list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7571635/fastest-way-to-check-if-a-value-exist-in-a-list)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `in` operator for that

```
a = (1,4)
b = [(3,5),(7,3),(6,9),(1,4)] 
print (a in b)
>>> 'True'
```

Comment: Thanks for you;re super quick answer :) I have tried this but it gives error that function is not iterable. As I want to say if a in b ==True: then for it to do an action??

Comment: @ATN you should do it like this: `print ((a in b) == True)`, Although it's not the right coding style, the answer i wrote is the appropriate way.  (a in b) equals to ((a in b) == True), but the code is more elegant the first way.