# I want the user to enter a number and if that number is not in the list provided the program will ask him to enter that number again

Tags: python

```
list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
number = input("Please enter a number: ")
number = int(number)
while True:
    if number != (any element of the list):
        number = input("Please enter a number: ")
    else:
        break
```

I want the user to enter a number and if that number is not in the list provided the program will ask him to enter that number again until he gets it write

Comment: `if number not in allowed_numbers`

Comment: @Chris_Rands That page has lots of excellent advice about getting user input, but it doesn't specifically address this question of checking whether a list contains a particular item.

Comment: Between the two you should be able to get it.

Comment: @PM2Ring You're right of course. Perhaps it's more this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7571635/fastest-way-to-check-if-a-value-exist-in-a-list). I'm never quite sure how to address these questions that are not truly original, but perhaps cross multiple questions.

Answer (score 0):

First you must initalize variable "number"
E.g.:

```
number = -1  # Init value should be value not included in list
```

List variable name, can't be "list". [List](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#list) is the name of Python builtin class.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the `in` statement to reach your goal. 
Your code can be similar to this:

```
list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
number = input("Please enter a number: ")
number = int(number)
while True:
    if not number in list:
        number = input("Please enter a number: ")
        number = int(number)
    else:
        break
```

Remember that you can have an exception not handled, I mean, if user insert something different to a number, your code raises an exception. 
Please consider to handle this with a `try except` statement

Answer (score -1):

```
list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
number = input("Please enter a number: ")
while True:
    if number not in list:
        number = input("Please enter a number: ")
    else:
        break
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.