# Faster to assign dictionary value to variable, or continually access?

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, dictionary

I have a dictionary such as:

```py
d = {'a':'a-val', 'b':'b-val', 'c':'c-long-val'*1000}
```

And I need to repeatedly access `d['c']` as in:

```py
print('value of c is', d['c'])
x_queue.put(d['c'])
some_function(d['c'])
```

But I'm wondering if it would be faster to assign `d['c']` to a variable and use it each time:

```py
c_value = d['c']` # is this assignment "worth it"?
print('value of c is', c_value)
x_queue.put(c_value)
some_function(c_value)
```

My hunch is it may depend on

- number of elements in `d` (finding key is more costly with bigger `d`)
- size of `d['c']` (assignment is more costly with bigger `d['c']`)

But I'm really not sure if one of those options (or another?) is *faster* or *more pythonic*.

Comment: Just try, measure and decide...

Comment: Thanks, I could (and will) try and measure for my specific case, but I still would like to know *why* one turns out better - if it does. Are my assumptions of the cost tradeoffs above correct?

Comment: In almost all languages, getting a value from a variable is usually faster than retrieving it from a container.

Comment: One just reads from a memory location, the other has to perform some extra calculation.

Comment: There are some exceptions, like variables in closures, which need to go through activation records.

Comment: For hunch #1: the size of the dict doesn't really matter, the only thing that can make access slower would be collisions in the hash table. For hunch #2: No copy takes place, your variable is just a new name for the object it refers to, so again the size doesn't matter. For #1, you can have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43690191/why-are-dict-lookups-always-better-than-list-lookups

Answer (score 1):

Although accessing a dict value by key has an average time complexity of *O(1)*, it has a worst-case time complexity of *O(n)* after incurring the overhead of calculating the hash value of the key. A variable assignment and the retrieval of its value on the other hand, take very minimal, constant time, so avoid re-evaluating a dict value by key whenever possible.

Comment: They're both O(1), but hashing has a larger coefficient.

Comment: Again, when I mentioned *O(n)* I was talking about the *worst-case* time complexity for the retrieval of a value from the dict heap after calculating the hash value.

Comment: In other words, you're confusing hashing (which takes *O(1)*) with hash collision resolution (which takes *O(n)* in worst case).

Comment: Big-O notation is the wrong thing to worry about here. Ignoring collision resolution, calculating a hash value is still much slower than reading a variable.

Answer (score 0):

The keys are hashed in a dictionary. So when you ask for d['c'], a hash is calculated first and then the corresponding value found. Lot more steps then a simple assignment.