# See if any value exists in list by looping

Tags: python, list

I do not know what I am missing but I've tried 3 different ways to achieve basically the same thing. Looking at the code below, why does only 1 out of the 4 ways work. I want to see if a value (located in a list) exists inside another list. I checked this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7571635/fastest-way-to-check-if-a-value-exist-in-a-list) but still not understanding why the code is failing to print `True1` , `True2`, and `True4`.

```
l1 = ["bravo", "alhpa", "charlie"]

l2 = ["alpha"]


if l1[1] in l2:
    print "True1"  # does not work

if l1[1] == l2[0]:
    print "True2"  # does not work

if "alpha" in l2:
    print "True3"  # works

for outer in l1:
    for inner in l2:
        if outer == inner:
            print "True4"  # does not work
```

Comment: Is it because you misspelled "alpha"?

Comment: @khelwood yes it is, this was honestly just a complete oversight, but here come all the down votes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo: `"alhpa"` vs. `"alpha"`

Comment: HOW EMBARRASSING!!!! Thank you! They all print now. Will accept as answer once it allows me to. That is what happens when I stare at just one thing too long