# Function that checks if the list contains a given as parameter value

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, python-3.x, parameters

So basically I want to write a function which checks if the list contains a given as parameter value.

For example:

```
l = ['ala', 'bala', 'alabala']
```

Comment: what are you trying to check? Why does `in` not work?

Comment: your example isn't really helpful. Either way, what have you tried so far to tackle this? Show your attempts if you have any.

Comment: What parameter this function need to detect? Can you elaborate more?

Comment: `if parameter_value in l: ...`?

Answer (score 2):

Simple function:

```
def isIn(item, list):
   return(item in list)

l = ['ala', 'bala', 'alabala']
print(isIn('bala',l))
```

As an example. Please google the answer before posting the question, or try to show what you have tried in the future.

[Fastest way to check if a value exist in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7571635/fastest-way-to-check-if-a-value-exist-in-a-list)

Shows any number of ways to do this

Comment: Better idea: Don't google solutions, but try to learn Python with the [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html).