# Does the 'in' operator use "==" or "is" for comparisons?

Tags: python, python-2.7, containment

In a Python expression like `str in [str1, str2, str3]` or `1 in [1, 2, 3]`, does the `in` operator use `==` or `is` to compare the first object with the objects in the list?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/48867273/6260170

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It depends on the object how `in` is executed; it is *not the `in` operator* that makes the comparison, it is the [`object.__contains__` method](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__contains__) that does the work.

For the Python standard container types (`list`, `tuple`, `set`, `dict`, etc.) *both identity and equality* are used. See the [*Membership test operations* section](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-operations) of the *Expressions* reference documentation:

> For container types such as `list`, `tuple`, `set`, `frozenset`, `dict`, or `collections.deque`, the expression `x in y` is equivalent to `any(x is e or x == e for e in y)`.

`is` is faster to test for, and objects having the same identity implies they are also equal.

Custom types are free to implement whatever test they want to do in their `__contains__` method.

Next, if no `__contains__` method is defined, but there is a `__iter__` method or a `__getitem__` method, then an iterative search is preformed where the values produced are tested for both identity and equality again. See the above linked documentation for details; the documentation is not that explicit about the identity test but the implementation still uses identity because using it is a performance boost.

You can see this when you use `float('nan')`, which is never equal to itself or anything else:

```
>>> nan = float('nan')
>>> nan == nan
False
>>> nan is nan
True
>>> nan in [nan]  # tests for identity first
True
>>> nan in iter([nan])  # an iterator, only __iter__ is defined
True
```

`float('nan')` is an *exception* to the normal expectation that identity implies equality; see [What is the rationale for all comparisons returning false for IEEE754 NaN values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565164/what-is-the-rationale-for-all-comparisons-returning-false-for-ieee754-nan-values) for why that is.

Comment: Your summary (saying "for [...] standard container types [...] equality is used") contradicts your quote from the docs. Membership tests for built-ins use *both* identity *and* value equality tests, testing identity first, then equality if the identity test fails.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: yes, it's late and I should really just call it a night. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to use `==`. With the following test:

```
Python 2.7.14 (default, Mar  1 2018, 19:24:37)
$ str1 = 'a bc'
$ str1 is 'a bc' # returns False
$ str1 in ['a bc'] # returns True
```

Any links to official documentation about this would be appreciated! My Google-fu has failed me thus far.