# Python find whole line in output

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I'm running a command where the output is a list of numbers:

```
output = subprocess.run(['command'], stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
```

The output (`output.stdout.decode('utf-8')`) is something like this:

```
1
534
89
4
57
9
```

I need to find if a specific number is not in that list. The problem is if I search using `if num not in list:` for num=3 I will get true since the number 534 is in that list.

How can I check if a number (in a line of its own) is in the list?

Comment: change `num=3` to `num="3"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fastest way to check if a value exist in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7571635/fastest-way-to-check-if-a-value-exist-in-a-list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just split your list and check either for "word" or for integer, using set comprehension to get rid of duplicates:

```
if 3 in {int(x) for x in output.stdout.decode('utf-8').split()}:
```

a simpler way is also possible with the direct output of `split`:

```
if "3" in output.stdout.decode('utf-8').split():
```

(less powerful if integers can start with 0: `03`)

Answer (score 0):

Just adding to the answer by Jean-Francois . Split() by default splits on white spaces, but since you would be needing to split on lines, I would suggest split('\n') to do the splitting, this way the code would be more resilient

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re` module as well:

```
import re

lookup=3

pattern = re.compile('\b{}\b'.format(lookup))

if pattern.search(output.stdout.decode('utf-8')):
    ...
```