# How to check if a nested list has certain value

Tags: python, list, multidimensional-array

I try to check if there is the integer 0 in my array.
There are similar topics around here but none of them is exactly what I need.
At first I thought this: [Fastest way to check if a value exist in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7571635/fastest-way-to-check-if-a-value-exist-in-a-list)
was what I was looking for but it doesn't work with multidimensional arrays (or lists of lists as you call them in Python) I believe.

So here is what I got so far:

```
myList = [[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]] 

while 0 in myList: # here is the problem. This statement is never true 
                   # but 'while [0,0,0]' is
    # do stuff

print(myList)
```

I can think of a solution that iterates through all the Elements using 2 loops but I was hoping there was an easier way.

I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

[chain](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) could be helpful

```
from itertools import chain
0 in chain(*[[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]] )
```

Comment: `0 in chain.fromiterable(myList)`, *perhaps*. But `any(0 in sub for sub in myList)` is perhaps cleaner.