# python - iterate through JSON list to match specific key value pair

Tags: python

I want to iterate through a JSON response to match specific key value pair to print it and another value in the same list.

The JSON looks like

```
[
{
    "status": "ok",
    "slot": null,
    "name": "blah",
    "index": 0,
    "identify": "off",
    "details": null,
    "speed": null,
    "temperature": null
},
{
    "status": "ok",
    "slot": null,
    "name": "blah1",
    "index": 0,
    "identify": "off",
    "details": null,
    "speed": null,
    "temperature": null
},
{
    "status": "ok",
    "slot": null,
    "name": "blah2",
    "index": 1,
    "identify": "off",
    "details": null,
    "speed": null,
    "temperature": null
}
]
```

The code i tried so far:

```
 url = http://something
 data = json.loads(r.get(url, headers=headers, verify=False).content.decode('UTF-8'))

 for value in data:
   if value['name'] == 'blah' or 'blah1':
        print(value)
```

And i tried with a next gen:

```
match = next(d for d in data if d['name'] == 'blah')
yield next(match)
```

But none of this worked.

The desired output i want is: If the `'name'='blah'` or `'name'='blah1'`, i want to print out **name** and the associated **status** with it.

`'name'='blah'`
`'status'='ok'`

`'name'='blah1'`
`'status'='ok'`

How can i do it with Python?

Comment: Nothing at all to do with JSON, this is a fundamental property of Python.

Comment: There's also not a `null` value in Python. It turns into `None` fyi

Comment: @Jaba Oops, sorry yea i pasted the JSON response. But when i do `json.loads` it should convert it to `none` right?

Comment: Yes, it will, but the answer is not predicated on that. It's a duplicate; you're not making the correct `if` checks. The JSON component makes it ripe for people to answer a regular Python question rather than flag as a dupe.

Comment: Yes it will, I assumed that's what happened

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for each `'name'` value check if it is [`in`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7571635/fastest-way-to-check-if-a-value-exist-in-a-list) the valid values:

```
for value in data:
    if value['name'] in ['blah', 'blah1']:
        print(value['name'], value['status'])
```

output:

```
u'blah', u'ok'
u'blah1', u'ok'
```

Update to question in comment:
To dynamically assign values to variable names, the most pythonic way to do this may be to use a dictionary to assign each variable name as the dictionary's `keys` and the corresponding `values` (taken from this answer [How can you dynamically create variables via a while loop? [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5036700/how-can-you-dynamically-create-variables-via-a-while-loop)):

```
import string

var = string.ascii_lowercase

d = {}
k = 0

for value in data:
    d[var[k]] = value['name']
    k += 1
    d[var[k]] = value['status']
    k += 1
```

Now we have a dictionary of variable names as keys that we can get their assigned values:

```
print(d['a']) # blah
```

Comment: That worked, now i want to dynamically assign the generated output to variables. Like, `a=blah` ,`b=blah1` , `c=ok` and `d=ok`. Even if there are 4 lines, i want to assign them dynamically, hope i made sense.

Comment: ok i will update and include that in the answer

Comment: @Bharath are you sure you want to assign variables to the data, would a dictionary also work?

Comment: @Bharath see updated answer. it's using a dictionary to get "variable" values. Let me know if this does not meet your needs and we can try something else.

Comment: Exactly what i wanted, you're a legend.

Comment: Oh actually, it prints out duplicates, like there are two `a` and `b`. When i do `print(d)` the output is `{'a': 'blah', 'b': 'ok'}
{'a': 'blah', 'b': 'ok', 'c': 'blah1', 'd': 'ok'}`

Comment: Alright, thanks for your feedback, I'll take a look and fix it ASAP

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187539/discussion-between-davedwards-and-bharath).

Answer (score 2):

I tried the below and it worked:

```
for value in data:
   if value['name'] == 'blah' or value['name'] == 'blah1':
      print(value)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using `next` on the value you get from `next` already. I'd use something like this:

```
data = [
{
    "status": "ok",
    "slot": None,
    "name": "blah",
    "index": 0,
    "identify": "off",
    "details": None,
    "speed": None,
    "temperature": None
},
{
    "status": "ok",
    "slot": None,
    "name": "blah1",
    "index": 0,
    "identify": "off",
    "details": None,
    "speed": None,
    "temperature": None
},
{
    "status": "ok",
    "slot": None,
    "name": "blah2",
    "index": 1,
    "identify": "off",
    "details": None,
    "speed": None,
    "temperature": None
}
]

#This is the part you're trying to work
def get_name(data, name):
  return next(d for d in data if d.get('name', None) == name)

v = get_name(data, "blah")
if v:
  print(f"Name: {v['name']}, Status: {v['status']}")
else:
  print("No Value")
```

This prints:

```
"Name: blah, Status: ok"
```

Comment: Thanks very much, i will try this now.