# How to check if a list is in a list of lists?

Tags: python-3.x, list, compare

i'm scraping a webpage for posts and saving the posts to a csv file and trying to prevent saving the same post more than once.

so far i can grab the posts and save them but im trying to compare the new posts to the ones i have already saved and failing. my code is:

```
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
r = requests.get("https://tpwd.texas.gov/state-parks/ray-roberts-lake/park_events")
page = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
events = page.find("div", "eventlist_month")
tweeted =[]
read = []
tweet = []
tweets = []
with open("C:/Users/Shua/Desktop/output.csv", "r") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:

        read = row
        tweeted.append(read)
        #print (read)

for tags in events.find_all("div", "vevent event"):
    event_date = tags.find("abbr", "dtstart").text.strip()
    event_title = tags.find("h3").text
    event_local = tags.find("div", "location").text
    event_sum = tags.find("div", "description").text
    event_url = tags.find("a")["href"]
    event_date2 = " ".join(event_date.split())
    tweet = [event_date2+" "+event_title+"\n"+event_sum+"\n"+event_local+" "+event_url]
    result = any(elem in tweet for elem in tweeted)
    print (tweeted)
    print(tweet)
    print(result)
    if result:
        print("saved")
    else:
        print("not save")
    tweets.append(tweet)
```

and the output is

```
[["Jun 28 Dutch Oven Cookin'\nJoin us for a tasty cooking lesson!\nRay Roberts Lake State Park - Isle Du Bois Unit https://tpwd.texas.gov/calendar/ray-roberts-lake-isle-du-bois-unit/dutch-oven-breakfast"], ['Jun 28 Friday Night Frog Talk\nCome see our green, long-legged friends!\nRay Roberts Lake State Park - Johnson Branch Unit https://tpwd.texas.gov/calendar/ray-roberts-lake-johnson-branch-unit/friday-night-frog-talk-8'], ['Jun 28 Wonders of the Night\nJoin a ranger for a night hike to find what goes bump in the night!\nRay Roberts Lake State Park - Isle Du Bois Unit https://tpwd.texas.gov/calendar/ray-roberts-lake-isle-du-bois-unit/wonders-of-the-night-2'], ['Jun 29 Guided Nature Hike\nLearn about the local flora and fauna with a Texas Master Naturalist volunteer.\nRay Roberts Lake State Park - Isle Du Bois Unit https://tpwd.texas.gov/calendar/ray-roberts-lake-isle-du-bois-unit/master-naturalist-guided-hike-5'], ['Jun 29 Hike with a Ranger!\nHike with a Ranger through Dogwood Canyon.\nRay Roberts Lake State Park - Johnson Branch Unit https://tpwd.texas.gov/calendar/ray-roberts-lake-johnson-branch-unit/dogwood-canyon-hike-2'], ["Jun 29 Pond Dipping\nLet's explore the pond life!\nRay Roberts Lake State Park - Johnson Branch Unit https://tpwd.texas.gov/calendar/ray-roberts-lake-johnson-branch-unit/pond-dipping"], ['Jun 29 Arts in the Park\nTry your hand at watercolors!\nRay Roberts Lake State Park - Johnson Branch Unit https://tpwd.texas.gov/calendar/ray-roberts-lake-johnson-branch-unit/arts-in-the-park-1']]
["Jun 28 Dutch Oven Cookin'\nJoin us for a tasty cooking lesson!\nRay Roberts Lake State Park - Isle Du Bois Unit https://tpwd.texas.gov/calendar/ray-roberts-lake-isle-du-bois-unit/dutch-oven-breakfast"]
False
not save
[["Jun 28 Dutch Oven Cookin'\nJoin us for a tasty cooking lesson!\nRay Roberts Lake State Park - Isle Du Bois Unit https://tpwd.texas.gov/calendar/ray-roberts-lake-isle-du-bois-unit/dutch-oven-breakfast"], ['Jun 28 Friday Night Frog Talk\nCome see our green, long-legged friends!\nRay Roberts Lake State Park - Johnson Branch Unit https://tpwd.texas.gov/calendar/ray-roberts-lake-johnson-branch-unit/friday-night-frog-talk-8'], ['Jun 28 Wonders of the Night\nJoin a ranger for a night hike to find what goes bump in the night!\nRay Roberts Lake State Park - Isle Du Bois Unit https://tpwd.texas.gov/calendar/ray-roberts-lake-isle-du-bois-unit/wonders-of-the-night-2'], ['Jun 29 Guided Nature Hike\nLearn about the local flora and fauna with a Texas Master Naturalist volunteer.\nRay Roberts Lake State Park - Isle Du Bois Unit https://tpwd.texas.gov/calendar/ray-roberts-lake-isle-du-bois-unit/master-naturalist-guided-hike-5'], ['Jun 29 Hike with a Ranger!\nHike with a Ranger through Dogwood Canyon.\nRay Roberts Lake State Park - Johnson Branch Unit https://tpwd.texas.gov/calendar/ray-roberts-lake-johnson-branch-unit/dogwood-canyon-hike-2'], ["Jun 29 Pond Dipping\nLet's explore the pond life!\nRay Roberts Lake State Park - Johnson Branch Unit https://tpwd.texas.gov/calendar/ray-roberts-lake-johnson-branch-unit/pond-dipping"], ['Jun 29 Arts in the Park\nTry your hand at watercolors!\nRay Roberts Lake State Park - Johnson Branch Unit https://tpwd.texas.gov/calendar/ray-roberts-lake-johnson-branch-unit/arts-in-the-park-1']]
['Jun 28 Friday Night Frog Talk\nCome see our green, long-legged friends!\nRay Roberts Lake State Park - Johnson Branch Unit https://tpwd.texas.gov/calendar/ray-roberts-lake-johnson-branch-unit/friday-night-frog-talk-8']
False
not save
[["Jun 28 Dutch Oven Cookin'\nJoin us for a tasty cooking lesson!\nRay Roberts Lake State Park - Isle Du Bois Unit https://tpwd.texas.gov/calendar/ray-roberts-lake-isle-du-bois-unit/dutch-oven-breakfast"], ['Jun 28 Friday Night Frog Talk\nCome see our green, long-legged friends!\nRay Roberts Lake State Park - Johnson Branch Unit https://tpwd.texas.gov/calendar/ray-roberts-lake-johnson-branch-unit/friday-night-frog-talk-8'], ['Jun 28 Wonders of the Night\nJoin a ranger for a night hike to find what goes bump in the night!\nRay Roberts Lake State Park - Isle Du Bois Unit https://tpwd.texas.gov/calendar/ray-roberts-lake-isle-du-bois-unit/wonders-of-the-night-2'], ['Jun 29 Guided Nature Hike\nLearn about the local flora and fauna with a Texas Master Naturalist volunteer.\nRay Roberts Lake State Park - Isle Du Bois Unit https://tpwd.texas.gov/calendar/ray-roberts-lake-isle-du-bois-unit/master-naturalist-guided-hike-5'], ['Jun 29 Hike with a Ranger!\nHike with a Ranger through Dogwood Canyon.\nRay Roberts Lake State Park - Johnson Branch Unit https://tpwd.texas.gov/calendar/ray-roberts-lake-johnson-branch-unit/dogwood-canyon-hike-2'], ["Jun 29 Pond Dipping\nLet's explore the pond life!\nRay Roberts Lake State Park - Johnson Branch Unit https://tpwd.texas.gov/calendar/ray-roberts-lake-johnson-branch-unit/pond-dipping"], ['Jun 29 Arts in the Park\nTry your hand at watercolors!\nRay Roberts Lake State Park - Johnson Branch Unit https://tpwd.texas.gov/calendar/ray-roberts-lake-johnson-branch-unit/arts-in-the-park-1']]
['Jun 28 Wonders of the Night\nJoin a ranger for a night hike to find what goes bump in the night!\nRay Roberts Lake State Park - Isle Du Bois Unit https://tpwd.texas.gov/calendar/ray-roberts-lake-isle-du-bois-unit/wonders-of-the-night-2']
False
not save
[["Jun 28 Dutch Oven Cookin'\nJoin us for a tasty cooking lesson!\nRay Roberts Lake State Park - Isle Du Bois Unit https://tpwd.texas.gov/calendar/ray-roberts-lake-isle-du-bois-unit/dutch-oven-breakfast"], ['Jun 28 Friday Night Frog Talk\nCome see our green, long-legged friends!\nRay Roberts Lake State Park - Johnson Branch Unit https://tpwd.texas.gov/calendar/ray-roberts-lake-johnson-branch-unit/friday-night-frog-talk-8'], ['Jun 28 Wonders of the Night\nJoin a ranger for a night hike to find what goes bump in the night!\nRay Roberts Lake State Park - Isle Du Bois Unit https://tpwd.texas.gov/calendar/ray-roberts-lake-isle-du-bois-unit/wonders-of-the-night-2'], ['Jun 29 Guided Nature Hike\nLearn about the local flora and fauna with a Texas Master Naturalist volunteer.\nRay Roberts Lake State Park - Isle Du Bois Unit https://tpwd.texas.gov/calendar/ray-roberts-lake-isle-du-bois-unit/master-naturalist-guided-hike-5'], ['Jun 29 Hike with a Ranger!\nHike with a Ranger through Dogwood Canyon.\nRay Roberts Lake State Park - Johnson Branch Unit https://tpwd.texas.gov/calendar/ray-roberts-lake-johnson-branch-unit/dogwood-canyon-hike-2'], ["Jun 29 Pond Dipping\nLet's explore the pond life!\nRay Roberts Lake State Park - Johnson Branch Unit https://tpwd.texas.gov/calendar/ray-roberts-lake-johnson-branch-unit/pond-dipping"], ['Jun 29 Arts in the Park\nTry your hand at watercolors!\nRay Roberts Lake State Park - Johnson Branch Unit https://tpwd.texas.gov/calendar/ray-roberts-lake-johnson-branch-unit/arts-in-the-park-1']]
['Jun 29 Guided Nature Hike\nLearn about the local flora and fauna with a Texas Master Naturalist volunteer.\nRay Roberts Lake State Park - Isle Du Bois Unit https://tpwd.texas.gov/calendar/ray-roberts-lake-isle-du-bois-unit/master-naturalist-guided-hike-5']
False
not save
[["Jun 28 Dutch Oven Cookin'\nJoin us for a tasty cooking lesson!\nRay Roberts Lake State Park - Isle Du Bois Unit https://tpwd.texas.gov/calendar/ray-roberts-lake-isle-du-bois-unit/dutch-oven-breakfast"], ['Jun 28 Friday Night Frog Talk\nCome see our green, long-legged friends!\nRay Roberts Lake State Park - Johnson Branch Unit https://tpwd.texas.gov/calendar/ray-roberts-lake-johnson-branch-unit/friday-night-frog-talk-8'], ['Jun 28 Wonders of the Night\nJoin a ranger for a night hike to find what goes bump in the night!\nRay Roberts Lake State Park - Isle Du Bois Unit https://tpwd.texas.gov/calendar/ray-roberts-lake-isle-du-bois-unit/wonders-of-the-night-2'], ['Jun 29 Guided Nature Hike\nLearn about the local flora and fauna with a Texas Master Naturalist volunteer.\nRay Roberts Lake State Park - Isle Du Bois Unit https://tpwd.texas.gov/calendar/ray-roberts-lake-isle-du-bois-unit/master-naturalist-guided-hike-5'], ['Jun 29 Hike with a Ranger!\nHike with a Ranger through Dogwood Canyon.\nRay Roberts Lake State Park - Johnson Branch Unit https://tpwd.texas.gov/calendar/ray-roberts-lake-johnson-branch-unit/dogwood-canyon-hike-2'], ["Jun 29 Pond Dipping\nLet's explore the pond life!\nRay Roberts Lake State Park - Johnson Branch Unit https://tpwd.texas.gov/calendar/ray-roberts-lake-johnson-branch-unit/pond-dipping"], ['Jun 29 Arts in the Park\nTry your hand at watercolors!\nRay Roberts Lake State Park - Johnson Branch Unit https://tpwd.texas.gov/calendar/ray-roberts-lake-johnson-branch-unit/arts-in-the-park-1']]
['Jun 29 Hike with a Ranger!\nHike with a Ranger through Dogwood Canyon.\nRay Roberts Lake State Park - Johnson Branch Unit https://tpwd.texas.gov/calendar/ray-roberts-lake-johnson-branch-unit/dogwood-canyon-hike-2']
False
not save
[["Jun 28 Dutch Oven Cookin'\nJoin us for a tasty cooking lesson!\nRay Roberts Lake State Park - Isle Du Bois Unit https://tpwd.texas.gov/calendar/ray-roberts-lake-isle-du-bois-unit/dutch-oven-breakfast"], ['Jun 28 Friday Night Frog Talk\nCome see our green, long-legged friends!\nRay Roberts Lake State Park - Johnson Branch Unit https://tpwd.texas.gov/calendar/ray-roberts-lake-johnson-branch-unit/friday-night-frog-talk-8'], ['Jun 28 Wonders of the Night\nJoin a ranger for a night hike to find what goes bump in the night!\nRay Roberts Lake State Park - Isle Du Bois Unit https://tpwd.texas.gov/calendar/ray-roberts-lake-isle-du-bois-unit/wonders-of-the-night-2'], ['Jun 29 Guided Nature Hike\nLearn about the local flora and fauna with a Texas Master Naturalist volunteer.\nRay Roberts Lake State Park - Isle Du Bois Unit https://tpwd.texas.gov/calendar/ray-roberts-lake-isle-du-bois-unit/master-naturalist-guided-hike-5'], ['Jun 29 Hike with a Ranger!\nHike with a Ranger through Dogwood Canyon.\nRay Roberts Lake State Park - Johnson Branch Unit https://tpwd.texas.gov/calendar/ray-roberts-lake-johnson-branch-unit/dogwood-canyon-hike-2'], ["Jun 29 Pond Dipping\nLet's explore the pond life!\nRay Roberts Lake State Park - Johnson Branch Unit https://tpwd.texas.gov/calendar/ray-roberts-lake-johnson-branch-unit/pond-dipping"], ['Jun 29 Arts in the Park\nTry your hand at watercolors!\nRay Roberts Lake State Park - Johnson Branch Unit https://tpwd.texas.gov/calendar/ray-roberts-lake-johnson-branch-unit/arts-in-the-park-1']]
["Jun 29 Pond Dipping\nLet's explore the pond life!\nRay Roberts Lake State Park - Johnson Branch Unit https://tpwd.texas.gov/calendar/ray-roberts-lake-johnson-branch-unit/pond-dipping"]
False
not save
[["Jun 28 Dutch Oven Cookin'\nJoin us for a tasty cooking lesson!\nRay Roberts Lake State Park - Isle Du Bois Unit https://tpwd.texas.gov/calendar/ray-roberts-lake-isle-du-bois-unit/dutch-oven-breakfast"], ['Jun 28 Friday Night Frog Talk\nCome see our green, long-legged friends!\nRay Roberts Lake State Park - Johnson Branch Unit https://tpwd.texas.gov/calendar/ray-roberts-lake-johnson-branch-unit/friday-night-frog-talk-8'], ['Jun 28 Wonders of the Night\nJoin a ranger for a night hike to find what goes bump in the night!\nRay Roberts Lake State Park - Isle Du Bois Unit https://tpwd.texas.gov/calendar/ray-roberts-lake-isle-du-bois-unit/wonders-of-the-night-2'], ['Jun 29 Guided Nature Hike\nLearn about the local flora and fauna with a Texas Master Naturalist volunteer.\nRay Roberts Lake State Park - Isle Du Bois Unit https://tpwd.texas.gov/calendar/ray-roberts-lake-isle-du-bois-unit/master-naturalist-guided-hike-5'], ['Jun 29 Hike with a Ranger!\nHike with a Ranger through Dogwood Canyon.\nRay Roberts Lake State Park - Johnson Branch Unit https://tpwd.texas.gov/calendar/ray-roberts-lake-johnson-branch-unit/dogwood-canyon-hike-2'], ["Jun 29 Pond Dipping\nLet's explore the pond life!\nRay Roberts Lake State Park - Johnson Branch Unit https://tpwd.texas.gov/calendar/ray-roberts-lake-johnson-branch-unit/pond-dipping"], ['Jun 29 Arts in the Park\nTry your hand at watercolors!\nRay Roberts Lake State Park - Johnson Branch Unit https://tpwd.texas.gov/calendar/ray-roberts-lake-johnson-branch-unit/arts-in-the-park-1']]
['Jun 29 Arts in the Park\nTry your hand at watercolors!\nRay Roberts Lake State Park - Johnson Branch Unit https://tpwd.texas.gov/calendar/ray-roberts-lake-johnson-branch-unit/arts-in-the-park-1']
False
not save
```

i have printed the list and the item i am trying to compare for each time to troubleshoot but i don't understand why its coming up false each time?
it seems to me that each comparison should be true as the list object is present...

Comment: Try replacing `any(elem in tweet for elem in tweeted)` with a for loop and a `found` variable. Print out `elem` per iteration. Maybe this will show the problem...

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply use:

```
result = tweet in tweeted
```

As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7571635/fastest-way-to-check-if-a-value-exist-in-a-list), the 'in' operator is used to check if an element exists in a list.