# Python :is there any way to know the dictionary exists in the list

Tags: python, list

```
some_list = [{"email":"were@mail.com","id_array":1234},{"email":"repo@mail.com","id_array":9887}]
```

for example I want to know whether `were@mail.com` email exists or not in the list.

Comment: Have you tried to do this yourself with e.g. a for-loop?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you could just use this:

```
any(item["email"] == "were@mail.com" for item in some_list)
# True
```

iterate over `some_list` and check if [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) of its items has the given email.

if you need to do this check often, you could speed it up by generating a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=set#set) that contains the mails only and then check with `in`:

```
email_set = set(item["email"] for item in some_list)

"were@mail.com" in email_set
# True
```

Answer (score 0):

Using list comprehension:

```py
emails = [i['email'] for i in some_list]
```

```py
[In]: 'were@mail.com' in emails
[Out]:
True
```

Also don't hesitate to check out efficiency of other methods if your list is big (after creating the list with only the mails): [Fastest way to check if a value exist in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7571635/fastest-way-to-check-if-a-value-exist-in-a-list)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this:-

```
some_list = [{"email":"were@mail.com","id_array":1234}, 
              {"email":"repo@mail.com","id_array":9887}]

email_list = []
for var in some_list:
    email_list.append(var['email'])
if "were@mail.com" in email_list:
    print("Yes you have required email.")
else:
    print("No you do not have required email")
```

I hope it may help you.