# Error validating whether first letter of string in list is a vowel, solutions?

Tags: python, validation

Apologies for the bad formatting, it is my first post.
I'm currently trying to return a list of words that begin with vowels from a given list, yet it is returning nothing. Is there a possibility for assistance?

```
x = ["A","B","C","D","E","F",]
wordList = []
for i in x:
  if i[0].lower() == ['a','e','i','o','u']:
    wordList.append(i)
return wordList
```

Comment: A single character cannot be equal to an entire list. You are meant to use `in`.

Comment: @usr2564301 Thank you, much appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fastest way to check if a value exists in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7571635/fastest-way-to-check-if-a-value-exists-in-a-list)

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it:

```
x = ["A","B","C","D","E","F",]
wordList = [ i for i in x if i.lower().startswith(('a','e','i','o','u')) ]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 x = ["A","B","C","D","E","F",]
 wordList = []
 for i in x:
     if i.lower() in ['a','e','i','o','u']:
         wordList.append(i)
 return wordList
```

try this.you will get letters that are vowels. for words beginning with vowels you can do the following.

```
 x = ["A","B","C","D","E","F",]
 wordList = []
 for i in x:
     if i[0].lower() in ['a','e','i','o','u']:
         wordList.append(i)
 return wordList
```

do up vote if liked.