# I want output to be shown once in for loop

Tags: python

I want Else statement to be shown once if it's wrong. Please see the code which I tried.

```py
lists = ['apple','grape','pineapple','orange']

password = "xyz"
def pass1():
    for i in lists:
        if i == password:
            print("Accepted!", "Password : " + i)
            break
        else:
            print("Password not found! Try again")
pass1()
```

**Output:**

```
Password not found! Try again
Password not found! Try again
Password not found! Try again
Password not found! Try again

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: None of the items in `lists` matches the password, so the code is working as expected. Have you tried `return`-ing inside the `else` block?

Comment: Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7571635/fastest-way-to-check-if-a-value-exists-in-a-list - you don't need to iterate over your list. You can use the `in` keyword to test all values against your password criteria at once.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you can do that by removing the `else`, if the loop ends and you didn't find the password in the list then it doesn't exist.

```
lists = ['apple','grape','pineapple','orange']

password = "xyz"
def pass1():
    for i in lists:
        if i == password:
            print("Accepted!", "Password : " + i)
            return
    print("Password not found! Try again")
pass1()
```

Another and more pythonic way

```
def pass2():
    if password in lists:
        print(print("Accepted!", "Password : " + lists.index(password)))
    else:
        print("Password not found! Try again")
pass2()
```

I don't see why you're not passing the password as a parameter?

Maybe consider doing it as follow

```
def pass3(password, lists):
    if password in lists:
        print(print("Accepted!", "Password : " + lists.index(password)))
    else:
        print("Password not found! Try again")

lists = ['apple','grape','pineapple','orange']
password = "xyz"
pass3(password, lists)
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't need looping if you just only want to check if the value in the lists, just try this:

```
def pass1():
    if password in lists:
        print("Accepted!", "Password : " + password)
    else:    
        print("Password not found! Try again")
```

but if you still want to iterating the list you can use return like this:

```
def pass1():
    for i in lists:
        if i == password:
            return print("Accepted!", "Password : " + i)
    return print("Password not found! Try again")
```

because if you not use return the last code still be printed even the password is true.

Comment: I tried with the correct password and it shows 2 output  "Accepted!" and "Password not found! Try again". I want it to be either of them.

Comment: if you want to be either of them just remove the return.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it by using `else` on `for loop`
`else block` is executed only when every item is exhausted:

```
lists = ['apple','grape','pineapple','orange']

password = "xyz"
def pass1():
    for i in lists:
        if i == password:
            print("Accepted!", "Password : " + i)
            break
    else:
        print("Password not found! Try again")
pass1()
```

Comment: But "Password not found! Try again" prints till it does not matches with the correct answer. I want it to be one time.

Comment: Copy and paste my code and try yourself. It only prints one time.