# Fetch key of a value from dictionary with multiple values for single key

Tags: python, dictionary

Given a dictionary

```
collision_domain  = {0: [0, 1, 2], 1: [2, 3, 4]}
```

this code should output `domain 0`:

```
search = 1
for dom, node in collision_domain.items():
    if node == search:
        print("domain", dom)
```

How do we get that?

Comment: Is `1` equal to `[0, 1, 2]`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fastest way to check if a value exists in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7571635/fastest-way-to-check-if-a-value-exists-in-a-list)

Comment: I think dictionary keys have to be strings, try changing node==search to node==str(search)

Comment: @Lebster Integer keys are just fine.

Comment: @Lebster The main requirement for dict keys is that they must be hashable

Comment: @Pavitra To clear this up for you, `==` tests whether two objects are *equal* but you want to test whether `1` is *contained* in the list `[0, 1, 2]`. You need to use the `in` operator instead of `==`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What we need to do here is search inside the list on each iteration of the loop.

Note that the search value comes first and then the list.
`if search in node:`

Final Code:

```
for dom, node in collision_domain.items():
    if search in node:
        print("domain", dom)
```