# Efficient matching between a large list of sentences and large list of words in python

Tags: python, pandas, search

**Introduction**

I know that there are many related questions on this platform to this and I have been researching and trying out different approaches from multiple options available. However, I wanted to collate all this and get suggestions on this problem.

**Problem**

I have a large file (~20M records) with a few parameters. On loading into a pandas data frame, it looks like this:

> **id | words_in_sentences      | freq**
>
> 1 | [county,went,live] | 400
>
> 2 | [going,on,mht00] | 500

I have another file that has roughly 300k words.

```
words=['on','mht','live']
```

Expected result:

I want to check whether each list in the column `'words_in_sentences'` contain any of these 300k words. It will be good to get one of the matching word as well.

> **id | words_in_sentences      | freq | is_word_present | word**
>
> ```
>   1 | [county,went,live] | 400 | True | live
>
>   2 | [going,on,mht00] | 500 | True | on
> ```

**Approaches**

1. Apply a look up function row-wise

```
        def lookup_none_simple(row):

            sent='words_in_sentences'
            
            
            row['matching_word']=[z for z in words if z in row[sent]]
                        
            return row
        
        none=none.apply(lambda row:lookup_none_simple(row),axis=1)
```

2. Approach 2:

Change the list to set and then apply the same function row wise.

`row['matching_word']=set(words).intersection(set(row[sent]))`

3. Use CountVectorizer for mapping words to numbers and go with the same logic.

**Issues**

- All these approaches are time consuming. I ran these methods on a large instance with 64GB RAM, still there were memory errors.

**Other approaches**

Use multiprocessing

- Use JOBLIB
- Use Multiprocessing
- Use DASK for the searches
- Use SPARK ( Didn't try)

I am finding it extremely hard to reduce the time taken for this task. Can somebody give an advice.

Comment: What is the length of the lists in 'words_in_sentences' column. is it constant?

Comment: Length of the lists in 'words_in_sentences' is between 3 to 20 words. On average, it will be around 6 words.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7571635/fastest-way-to-check-if-a-value-exists-in-a-list - Very useful post

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know how big a dataset this method can handle. But it works fine on small dataset. Maybe you can split the dataframe into batches of say 200K and apply this method in a loop. You can use the explode() method in pandas and then do a join with words.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'words_in_sentences':[['county','went','live'], ['going','on','mht00', 'dum'],
                                    ['abc', 'def']],
                  'freq':[400, 500, 600]})
df['id'] = df.index

words=['on','mht','live']
df_words = pd.DataFrame({'words':words})

df_exp = df[['id', 'words_in_sentences']].explode('words_in_sentences')
df_exp = df_exp.merge(df_words, left_on = 'words_in_sentences', right_on = 'words')
df_matched = df_exp.groupby('id', as_index=False).agg({'words':list})
df_matched['is_word_present'] = True

df = df.merge(df_matched, on = 'id', how = 'left')
df['is_word_present'] = df.is_word_present.fillna(False)
```