# Input from user doesn't compare with array properly

Tags: python, arrays

There is a bit of code that I need to implement for the program I am writing (my first ever code project, not too great with programing yet) and my comparison with a users input and an array is not working. It is meant to check that the users input choice is present in the array and adding the input to a variable, but it keeps printing "Player not on this team, try again".

```
    while first_bowl == False:
        bowler = input("Who is bowling first?: ")
        if bowler == Team1:
            first_bowl = True
            print('first bowler is {bowler}')
        elif bowler != Team1:
            print("Player not on this team, try again")
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: You probably want `bowler in Team1` and `bowler not in Team1`, but you don't actually need an `elif`, just an `else`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fastest way to check if a value exists in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7571635/fastest-way-to-check-if-a-value-exists-in-a-list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if you an element is present in a list, you can use `in`.

```
    while first_bowl == False:
        bowler = input("Who is bowling first?: ")
        if bowler in Team1:
            first_bowl = True
            print('first bowler is {bowler}')
        else:
            print("Player not on this team, try again")
```

Comment: Never knew there was an "in" function, very nice!

Answer (score 1):

Use `in` operator to check if item is in list:

```
while first_bowl == False:
  bowler = input("Who is bowling first?: ")
  if bowler in Team1:
    first_bowl = True
    print('first bowler is {bowler}')
  else:
    print("Player not on this team, try again")
```

Answer (score 0):

Do that if you want to find a certain string in your list, let's say you want to check if John is in Team 1:

```
if 'John' in Team1:
    first_bowl = True
    print('First bowler is {bowler}')
```

But if you ask the user for an input, he can specify the variable, so it gets put into string and then into the variable "bowler", so as a result you can do:

```
if bowler in Team1:
    first_bowl = True
    print('First bowler is {bowler}')
```

Which basically checks if the string variable "bowler" provided by the user is in the list named Team 1.