# How to check which elements of one iterable are also in another?

Tags: python

I have two tuples of possibly different lengths:

```
t1 = ('abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl')
t2 = ('def', 'jkl')
```

I need to get a resulting tuple that contains `bool`, holding `True` if the value in `t1` is in `t2` and `False` otherwise.

I am looking for the following result:

```
result = (False, True, False, True)
```

Comment: Should be straightforward. Loop over t1 and check if element is in t2.

Comment: [Fastest way to check if a value exists in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7571635/6045800) in a loop on `t1`....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using a generator expression and the tuple constructor, you can iterate over `t1` and check if each element is in `t2`:

```py
result = tuple(element in t2 for element in t1)
```

If `t2` is a large tuple, it may be faster to convert it to a `set` first.

```py
s2 = set(t2)
result = tuple(element in s2 for element in t1)
```

Answer (score 0):

With Python 3.6+, since it maintains insertion order, you can do this using `.fromkeys()` and `.update()`:

```py
di = dict.fromkeys(t1, False)
di.update(dict.fromkeys(t2, True))
# di = {'abc': False, 'def': True, 'ghi': False, 'jkl': True}
 
>>> tuple(di.values())
(False, True, False, True)
```

Which can be shortened to:

```
results=tuple({ **{}.fromkeys(t1, False), **{}.fromkeys(t2, True) }.values())
```

Or, with Python 3.9+:

```
result=tuple(({}.fromkeys(t1, False) | {}.fromkeys(t2, True)).values())
```

If you want to make sure that a value in `t2` is not inserted into result as `True` without a corresponding value in `t1`, just have a `set` to determine the overlapping elements:

```
result=tuple(({}.fromkeys(t1, False) | {}.fromkeys(set(t1)&set(t2), True)).values())
```

This method is potentially [faster](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40963434/298607) for larger sequences since `in` can be slower for long sequences.