# I would like to find a neat way to check if a string is in a list and, if so, return the index

Tags: python, list, indexing

This works:

```
def find_file_ix(fn,fn_list):
   
    if fn in fn_list:
        ix=fn_list.index(fn)
    else:
        ix=-1
    return ix

l=['a','b','c','d','e']

print(find_file_ix('d',l))
print(find_file_ix('z',l))
```

and prints 3, -1 as expected.

I could accomplish the same thing with a try/except sequence. However, I find both clumsy and the above code seems to have an element of redundancy - surely the 'in' test must have already found the index?

Comment: Check out: [Fastest way to check if a value exists in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7571635/fastest-way-to-check-if-a-value-exists-in-a-list/58844693#58844693)

Comment: While using *-1* as an indicator of an unexpected event is perfectly fine, it is error prone because *-1* is a valid index in python. I think *try* is safer and more pythonic in this case. The *in* operator could return the index for lists, but not for other collection types that don't support indexing.

Comment: Thanks Michael. I actually modelled the -1 on the way that find works. I can see the danger. (I am an old assembly language, Fortran, Cobol - a touch of Pascal - programmer who is learning Python for fun. It is sometimes hard to work out what the 'best' way of doing something is. 'Best' can mean 'most elegant', 'quickest', 'most understandable', 'safest' ... I appreciate all the help I can get!)