# Check if multi dimensional list element exists in another list

Tags: python

Consider these two lists:

ListA = ["High", [1,2,3], "Medium"]
ListB = [["Low", [3,2,1], "Low"], ["High", [1,2,3], "Medium"]]

Now I want to check if ListA exists in ListB.
In this example, it should give TRUE since ListA equals ListB[1].

Normally I would convert the list to a set so all duplicates get removed, however, since this is not a flat list I'm stuck finding a good way to solve this.

Comment: `if ListA in ListB` will do it.

Comment: weird, i tried that already before posting but it still says true even if it doesn't exist in the second list..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fastest way to check if a value exists in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7571635/fastest-way-to-check-if-a-value-exists-in-a-list)

Comment: You may have a bug in your code, this `in` works fine for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ListA in ListB:
    print('ListA exists in ListB.')
```

Comment: this doesnt work

Comment: @Azrion why it does not work? Can you put an example?

Comment: @Azrion, I checked it in the Python interpreter before posting. Why do you say it doesn't work? Can you share your code?

Comment: ok i figured it out its my dumb mistake with a bug... i change ListA[0] to some random value and then checked if it exists in ListA. obviously it returns true because I didn't run a deepcopy...