# The results in for loop flask did not meet the requirements

Tags: python, jinja2

I want result are s0 s1 p2 s3 s4 s5 s6 s7 p8 s9 but result in my code are s0 s1 p2 s3 s4 s5 s6 s7 s8 s9 s0 s1 s2 s3 s4 s5 s6 s7 p8 s9  please help me

```
{% for x in [2,8] %}<br>
{% for i in range(10) %}
    {% if i == x|int %}
        p{{i}}
    {% else %}
        s{{i}}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: It's not clear what are the values in the list. Can you paste the values from the list too?

Comment: I don't really understand List, but the values in [ ] I query from the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{% for i in range(10) %}
    {% if i in [2,8]|list  %}
        p{{i}}
    {% else %}
        s{{i}}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are running 1-10 loop 2 times (number of changes). instead run 1-10 one time and check is it in change list.

```
 {% for i in range(10) %}<br>
 {% for x in [2,8]|list %} 
 {% if i == x|int %}
    p{{i}}
 {% else %}
    s{{i}}
 {% endif %}
 {% endfor %}
 {% endfor %}
```

if change list is bigger then u can use faster methods like `index()`. for more
refer [Fastest way to check if a value exists in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7571635/fastest-way-to-check-if-a-value-exists-in-a-list)