# print array variables task in python

Tags: python

I'm currently learning python and doing some basic tasks but I'm having difficulties with this code:

```
names = ["Terry", "Ben", "Mike"]
name = input("oya enter name ")
if names == name:
     print("Welcome " + name)
else:
     print("Who are you???!!!")
```

I'm trying to get the user to input a name and if the name is not in the array the code will print the else command but when I run the code and enter one of the names it does not work. Any solution please?

Comment: Please repost your code with proper formatting. Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: `if names == name:` should be `if name in names:`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fastest way to check if a value exists in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7571635/fastest-way-to-check-if-a-value-exists-in-a-list)

Answer (score 1):

```
names = ["Terry", "Ben", "Mike"]
name = input("oya enter name ")
if name in names:
     print("Welcome " + name)
else:
     print("Who are you???!!!")
```

All you have to do is write `name in names`.

Comment: Also, using f-strings might be easier to read than string concatenation: `print(f"Welcome {name}.")`.