# lists comparing with nested values

Tags: python

I have a list of objects, that among other attributes have an attribute named "id"

```
listA = [{"id":"5","age":"44"},{"id":"8","age":"34"},{"id":"15","age":"84"}]
```

I have a list of strings such as :

```
listB = ["9","1","7","5","10","15","20"]
```

I wish to extract into a third list, all object ids from listA that have an id value in listB

the expected result would be :

```
listResult = ["5","15"]
```

How can I do this without using loops?

Comment: `[obj["id"] for obj in listA if obj["id"] in listB]`?  That's a loop, but then so would be any other reasonable solution to the problem.

Comment: _"How can I do this without using loops?"_ you can't

Comment: @PranavHosangadi maybe they wan't to avoid the use of `for` and `while`, although I agree that with `map` and `filter` you are still looping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
listA = [{"id":"5","age":"44"},{"id":"8","age":"34"},{"id":"15","age":"84"}]
listB = ["9","1","7","5","10","15","20"]
listC = [ x['id'] for x in listA if x['id'] in listB ]

print(listC) 
# ['5', '15']
```

- Get each `x['id']` for each `x` in `listA` where `x['id'] in listB`
- The `in` means if `x['id']` exists in `listB`:
  [Fastest way to check if a value exists in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7571635/fastest-way-to-check-if-a-value-exists-in-a-list)

Answer (score 3):

Another way is using `set` and the `intersection` method:

```
listA = [{"id":"5","age":"44"},{"id":"8","age":"34"},{"id":"15","age":"84"}]
listB = ["9","1","7","5","10","15","20"]

listC = list(set(listB).intersection(set(d['id'] for d in listA)))
print(listC)
```

The result is `['15', '5']`.

Comment: The `set` constructor takes generator expressions so you can avoid the list comprehension around `d['id'] for ...`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter` and `list` to achieve it, although it would make more sense to simply use list comprehension like in @0stone0 answer.

```py
list_a = [{"id":"5","age":"44"},{"id":"8","age":"34"},{"id":"15","age":"84"}]
list_b = ["9","1","7","5","10","15","20"]
list_a_ids = map(lambda object: object['id'], list_a)
list_result = list(filter(lambda id: id in list_b, list_a_ids))
```

Answer (score 0):

Combining the filter() and map() function with an unpacking assignment will do it without an explicit loop (although these function do perform loops internally):

```
*listResult, = filter(listB.__contains__,map(lambda d:d["id"],listA))
```