# Is there a better way than this to add exceptions in a list comprehension for certain words?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I am making a basic library management system and I want to add exceptions for certain preposition words with a condition that the user can type the exceptional words in upper case, lower case or as a title, i.e. the first letter is capital.

I have made a separate list with such exceptions and the code is working fine but I want to know if there is a better way to do the same

```
class Library:
    def __init__(self, list_of_books):
        self.available_books = list_of_books

    def display_available_books(self):
        print()
        print("Available Books:")
        for books in self.available_books:
            print(books)

    def lend_book(self, requested_book):
        if requested_book in self.available_books:
            print(f"You have borrowed {requested_book}")
            self.available_books.remove(requested_book)
        else:
            print("Sorry, the book is not available")

    def add_book(self, returned_book):
        if returned_book not in self.available_books:  # This is with the assumption that only one copy of a book can
            # be present in the library at a time
            self.available_books.append(returned_book)
            print("You have returned the book. Thank you")
        else:
            print("The book is already in the library")


class Customer:
    def __init__(self):
        self.book = None

    def request_book(self):
        print("Enter the name of the book that you would like to borrow:")
        self.book = input()
        exception = ["and", "or", "at", "in", "for", "AND", "OR", "AT", "IN", "FOR", "And", "Or", "At", "In", "For"]
        self.book = " ".join([i.lower() if i in exception else i.capitalize() for i in self.book.
                             split()])
        print(self.book)
        return self.book

    def return_book(self):
        print("Enter the name of the book you want to return")
        self.book = input()
        exception = ["and", "or", "at", "in", "for", "AND", "OR", "AT", "IN", "FOR", "And", "Or", "At", "In", "For"]
        self.book = " ".join([i.lower() if i in exception else i.capitalize() for i in self.book.
                             split()])
        print(self.book)
        return self.book


library = Library(["Think and Grow Rich", "The Monk Who Sold His Ferrari", "Deep Work"])
customer = Customer()

while True:
    print("Enter 1 to display the available books")
    print("Enter 2 to request for a book")
    print("Enter 3 to return a book")
    print("Enter 4 to exit")
    user_choice = int(input())
    if user_choice == 1:
        library.display_available_books()
    elif user_choice == 2:
        book = customer.request_book()
        library.lend_book(book)
    elif user_choice == 3:
        book = customer.return_book()
        library.add_book(book)
    elif user_choice == 4:
        exit("Thank you!")
    else:
        print("Enter a valid input")
```

This is the specific code:

```
exception = ["and", "or", "at", "in", "for", "AND", "OR", "AT", "IN", "FOR", "And", "Or", "At", "In", "For"]
self.book = " ".join([i.lower() if i in exception else i.capitalize() for i in self.book.split()])
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

1. for your exception you should use a set, it is much faster to check, whether a certain items is contained for a set than a list
   [Fastest way to check if a value exists in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7571635/fastest-way-to-check-if-a-value-exists-in-a-list)
2. it is a bit quicker to make `exceptions` part of the class
3. I think you can handle it a bit more elegant, if you want to use `capitalize` on every word not contained in your exceptions (also this avoids, adding all the other exceptions like "aNd" and so on)
4. In general, you used the fastest method available. All other options (e.g. combinations of regex and replace) are way more inefficient

   ```
    class Customer:
        def __init__(self):
            self.book = None
            self.exception = set(["and", "or", "at", "in", "for"])

        def request_book(self):
            print("Enter the name of the book that you would like to borrow:")
            book = input()
            self.book = " ".join(
                [w.capitalize() if w not in self.exception else w
                 for w in book.lower().split()])
            print(self.book)
            return self.book
   ```