# Binary search to find the highest possible value in Python

Tags: python, numbers, binary-search-tree, binary-search

I have a very large number (20 digits), which I need to find. So in a range between 0 and 99999999999999999999.

I can perform a check if the number is larger or smaller than the guessed number, so for example:

```
is_smaller(12341234123412341234)
# True
is_smaller(98769876987698769876)
# False
```

However, how the function `is_smaller` works is unknown, but the value for a number is constant.

Could this be solved with a binary search - I'm not quite sure how I can implement this as I only ever know If the number is smaller/larger.
Most implementations of the binary search [I've come across](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9502063/5438714), use it to find a given number in an array, which doesn't work for me as the number is unknown.

How could I use binary search in this scenario, or would another method be better suited?

The goal is to find the highest possible value, that still returns `True` for `is_smaller`.

---

*edit:* I do not have a way of telling if the number is bigger, so I have no `is_bigger` function. So in a smaller range (e.g. 0 to 10), if the number of interest is **6**, the function I have would return:

```
[...]
is_smaller(4)
# True
is_smaller(5)
# True
is_smaller(6)
# True
is_smaller(7)
# False
is_smaller(8)
# False
```

I have to admit the functions name in the question was very poorly chosen.

Answer (score 2):

If something is neither bigger nor smaller than the number you're looking for, it's the number you're looking for.

```
def is_answer(n):
    return not is_smaller(n) and not is_larger(n)
```

Now you can use standard binary search; just replace conditionals that look like

```
if x == search_term:
if x < search_term:
if x > search_term:
```

With

```
if is_answer(x):
if is_smaller(x):
if is_larger(x):
```

Respectively. If you want a `<=` or `>=` operator for your binary search, you can construct it yourself from these building blocks.

Comment: Thank you very much for the feedback! I've edited the question as I have no way of telling if a number is bigger than the number of interest. It is either bigger, or the number itself (see the code example in the edit).

Answer (score 0):

Binary search splits a range from `lower_boundary .. higher_boundary` to the range `lower_boundary .. (lower_boundary + higher_boundary) // 2` or `(lower_boundary + higher_boundary) // 2 + 1 .. lower_boundary` depending on the outcome of your `is_smaller` function.