# how to find the last available url which does not return 302 (Redirect) status code in a url list quickly

Tags: python, algorithm, urllib2

Now I am facing a problem like this:

Say I have a list of urls, e.g.

```
['http://example.com/1', 
 'http://example.com/2', 
 'http://example.com/3',
 'http://example.com/4', 
 ..., 
 'http://example.com/100']
```

And some of them are unavailable urls, requesting for those urls will result in 302 redirect status code. e.g. .../1 - .../50 are available urls, but .../51 will cause 302. Then .../50 is the url I want.

I want to find out which url is the last availble url (which does not return 302 code), I believe binary search will do the work, but I wonder how to implement it with better efficiency. I use python's urllib2 to detect 302 status code.

p.s. e.g. .../1 - .../50 are available urls, but .../51 will cause 302. Then .../50 is the url I want.

Comment: Start at the end and search backwards until you find one that's available!

Comment: e.g. .../1 - .../50 are available urls, but .../51 will cause 302. Then .../50 is the url I want. How to return .../50 exactly ?

Comment: @Martijn: Binary search is only going to help if *every* URL after some position will cause 302. Is that the case, OP?

Comment: @j_random_hacker: true, that's what I meant to say all along.. :-P

Comment: So if 1-50 are good, 51 is bad, 52-90 are good, and 91-100 are bad, do you want 50 or 90?  Your paragraphs seem to contradict each other.  Do you want the last of the first batch of good, or the last of the good in the entire list?

Comment: If (as I suspect) there is no relationship between the URLs: Without testing it, how could you know whether some URL will produce a 302? So you need to test them all.

Comment: Is this data meaningfully ordered, or are you really just trying to find a good URL from a randomly sampled subset of the full URL list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer makes the assumption that your URLs *are* currently ordered in a meaningful way, and that all URLs up to some value `n` will be available and all URLs after `n` will result in a 302.

If this is the case, then you can adapt [this binary search answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/212413/505154) to fit your needs:

```
import requests

def binary_search_urls(urls, lo=0, hi=None):
    if hi is None:
        hi = len(urls)
    while lo < hi:
        mid = (lo+hi)//2
        status = requests.head(urls[mid]).status_code
        if status != 302:
            lo = mid+1
        else: 
            hi = mid
    return lo - 1
```

This will give you the index of the last good URL, or `-1` if there are no good URLs.

Comment: This won't work.  If the url at mid returns a 302, you know you can exclude mid > high from the remainder of the search, but if the url returns anything else, it tells you nothing about whether any of the values between low and high return 302, so you can't safely exclude either portion from the rest of the search.  When the url returns non 302, all you can safely do is move mid to some new point between low and high.

Comment: Given the assumption described in my answer, this will work.  The OP wants the last available URL, so if the URL at `mid` is valid then we exclude everything before `mid` (based on my assumption, they are all also valid).  This would set `lo` to `mid + 1`, and if no other valid URLs are found then `lo` won't be modified again and `lo - 1` is returned, which is that last available URL.

Comment: Fair enough.  Assuming information not in evidence, it would work.  :)

Comment: Thats why I state the assumption at the beginning of my answer, the question is unclear on this, if the OP clarifies that this is not the case I will delete the answer.  It also isn't unreasonable that this might be the case, for example if the goal is to find the highest implemented version of some versioned API where the only difference in the path is the version number.

Comment: Your assumption is quite accurate !

Answer (score 1):

I would just check the entire lot, **however** I would use `requests` instead of `urllib2` and make sure to only make `HEAD` requests to keep bandwith down (which is possibly going to be your greatest bottle neck anyway).

```
import requests

urls = [...]
results = [(url, requests.head(url).status_code) for url in urls]
```

Then go from there...

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how a binary search could be at all faster than straight in order iteration, and in most cases, it would end up being slower.  Given `n` is the length of the list, if you are searching for the last good url of the first good batch, only the case where `urls[n/2]-1` is your target would take the same number of searches as just brute force iteration; all others would take more.  If you are looking for the last good url in the entire list, the only search target that would take the same number of searches compared to a reversed order iteration would be `urls[n/2]-1`.  Binary search is only faster when your dataset is ordered.  For an unordered dataset, sampling the middle of the set tells you nothing about being able to exclude values to either side of it, so you still have to process the entire sequence before you can tell anything.

I suspect what you may really be wanting here is a way to sample your dataset at intervals so that you can run fewer requests before finding your target, which isn't quite the same as a binary search.  Binary search relies on the fact that sampling a point in your sequence provides information on being able to exclude either one side or the other of the sequence from subsequent searches based upon a binary condition.  What you have is a system where if a sample fails the test, you can exclude one side, but if it passes the test, it tells you nothing about what you can assume about any other values in the list.  That doesn't really work for a binary search.