# Python: Get index if in statement evaluates true

Tags: python, performance, indexing

I'm doing a simple lookup

```
if xo.st in sts:
    #...
```

If the condition is met I need to get the index of the element in sts (sts is a list or a tuple). This needs to be fast (it is a big list). What is the best solution for this?

Comment: What do you want to do if the condition is not met?

Comment: Nothing really. I'll add `None` to my data collection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about:

```
if xo.st in sts:
    print sts.index(xo.st)
```

This will return the first index of `xo.st` in`sts`

Comment: This solution will search the list two times: once to see if the item is in the list, and then a second time to get its instance! Better to just do `index()` and catch the `ValueError` as shown in Victor's solution. This will only search the list once.

Answer (score 3):

First thing that comes to mind is

```
list.index(xo.st)
```

Answer (score 3):

`list` and `tuple` both have an `index` method, which returns the index for a value if it's in the data, or raises a `ValueError` if it's not present.

If you want speed you might want to keep an ordered list and do a [binary search](http://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html)
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/212358/binary-search-in-python) is a previous SO about this.

Answer (score 2):

The `index` method, present in lists and tuples, is what you need.
It raises a `ValueError` when the value is NOT in the list.
If that's not what you want, you can make something like this:

```
>>> def get_index(value, sequence):
...     try:
...         return sequence.index(value)
...     except ValueError:
...         return None
... 
>>> l = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> print get_index(1, l)
0
>>> print get_index(2, l)
1
>>> print get_index(9, l)
None
```

Comment: Uh, `[1,2,3,4,5][-1]` will yield 5 in this case.  I think you might want to return `None` instead of -1.