# Searching an attribute_A in a attribute_B-sorted list

Tags: python, list, search, attributes

In Python, what is the most efficient way to search in a list which is sorted according to an attribute? See below for a more precise question.

Example:

```
class Any (object):
    def __init__(self, attr_a, attr_b):
        self.attr_a = attr_a
        self.attr_b = attr_b

L = [Any(-3, 4), Any(-2, 1), Any(0, 2), Any(2, 1), Any(5, 6), Any(6, 3), Any(8, 2), Any(10, 1), Any(13, 5), Any(14, 3)]
```

`L` is sorted according to the attribute `attr_a`. All `Any` instances of the list `L` have a different `attr_a` value. What is the most efficient way to search for the value of `attr_b` of the object which `attr_a` equals `x`?

Comment: The most efficient searching method for a sorted list is the bisection algorithm.  See [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/212358/binary-search-in-python) for an implementation in python (take a look at the one with the most votes).  You will need to modify it to find the attr_a, then get attr_b after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd adopt a binary search to find the right `Any` object for your `attr_a` value. The [`bisect` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html) provides a starting point:

```
def bisect_left(a, x, lo=0, hi=None, key=None):
    if key is None: key = lambda v: v
    if lo < 0:
        raise ValueError('lo must be non-negative')
    if hi is None:
        hi = len(a)
    while lo < hi:
        mid = (lo+hi)//2
        if key(a[mid]) < x: lo = mid+1
        else: hi = mid
    return lo
```

The only thing I did was add a `key` function to the signature here. `key` takes a callable that returns the value against we are bisecting.

Now you can use bisection to find your `Any` index:

```
from operator import attrgetter

index = bisect_left(L, x, key=attrgetter('attr_a'))
```

This returns either the index of a matching `Any`, or the index of the *next* `Any` object whose `attr_a` value is higher than `x`. You may need to test and/or adjust the algorithm for those cases. For example, you could verify that `attr_a` does indeed match the desired value:

```
def find_by_x(L, x, key):
    index = bisect_left(L, x, key=key)
    if key(L[index]) != x:
        raise IndexError('{} not found'.format(x))
    return L[index]
```

Demo:

```
>>> from operator import attrgetter
>>> L = [Any(-3, 4), Any(-2, 1), Any(0, 2), Any(2, 1), Any(5, 6), Any(6, 3), Any(8, 2), Any(10, 1), Any(13, 5), Any(14, 3)]
>>> x = 6
>>> bisect_left(L, x, key=attrgetter('attr_a'))
5
>>> L[bisect_left(L, x, key=attrgetter('attr_a'))].attr_b
3
>>> find_by_x(L, x, key=attrgetter('attr_a')).attr_b
3
>>> x = 12
>>> find_by_x(L, x, key=attrgetter('attr_a')).attr_b
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in find_by_x
IndexError: 12 not found
```

Comment: That's a really great solution!

Comment: Thanks a lot! great solution. I'm kinda affraid though that I could get the index (and so `attr_b`) of the `attr_a` value that follows `x`! In theory it shouldn't be a problem but we never know... How could I avoid that? How could I get an error message if no `Any` instance has an `attr_a` which equals `x`?

Comment: You'd have to verify that the object at that index has the expected value for `attr_a`.

Comment: I've added a sample function that verifies first.

Comment: Well, that's right I can just check that afterward. Thanks a lot for this great answer @MartijnPieters

Answer (score 0):

You want to use module [bisect](http://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html#module-bisect) and its `bisect_left` function. In your case you would need to extract list of the keys before using it, see section [Other examples](http://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html#other-examples) for detailed explanation. If this is not acceptable then you can implement your own version of binary search, it's a simple algorithm.