# python implicit binary search

Tags: python, performance

I have list which is already sorted.

I often need to check to see

```
if foo in sortedlist:
    pass  # not really.  but not the point.
```

Is there a way to teach 'in' that sortedlist is sorted and that it should binary search the list?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Binary Search in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/212358/binary-search-in-python)

Comment: Good question - It would be good to know how the search is conducted in sorted(my_list) too.

Comment: It's not possible to change the behavior of 'in'. What you're looking for is the the link pointed by Matt Ball (possible duplicate).

Comment: @ threadp: not quite true. See below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python favours explicit over implicit. Your options are to explicitly use the [`bisect` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html) if you know your data is sorted, or create a subclass of `list` that implements `__contains__` by using that module.

For example:

```
import bisect


class SortedList(list):
    def __contains__(self, elem):
        idx = bisect.bisect_left(self, elem)
        return idx < len(self) and self[idx] == elem
```

could be used as a substitute for `list`, and `in` will use `__contains__` automatically. You'd probably want to override `__setitem__`, `.extend()` and `.append()` to maintain the list in sorted order, too.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: your code is not correct: It raise a `IndexError: list index out of range` if elem is larger than the largest element of the list: the returned `idx` is `len(self)`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters not on my machine... You should definitely check on yours.

Comment: @hivert: ah, no, I was indeed forgetting the `elem > self[-1]` case. Thanks for pointing that out. Corrected.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion would be to subclass list to use sorted list:

```
from bisect import bisect_left
class SortedList(list):
    def __init__(self, l):
        list.__init__(self, sorted(l))
    def __contains__(self, obj):
        pos = bisect_left(self, obj, 0, len(self))
        return (pos != len(self) and self[pos] == obj)
```

Then:

```
>>> l = SortedList([4,3,5435,123,54,2,343,23])
>>> l
[2, 3, 4, 23, 54, 123, 343, 5435]
>>> 23 in l
True
>>> 25 in l
False
>>> 123122 in l
False
>>> -1 in l
False
```