# How do I delete rows in a pandas dataframe based on array of row indexes

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, dataframe, filtering

I have a data frame with points. The first two columns are positions. I am filtering the data based on a points proximity to another point. I calculate the distance of all the points with cdist and then filter this result to find the indices of the points that have a distance less 0.5 from each other. I also have to do two mini filters on these indices first to remove remove indices for comparing the same point distance [n,n] = distance [n,n] will always equal zero and I don't want to remove all of my points. Also I remove indeces for similar distance comparisons distance [n,m] = distance [m,n]. There are basically double the number of points that I need to remove so I use unique to filter out half.

My questions `loc_find` is a numpy array of indexes to rows that should be removed. How do I remove use this array to remove these numbered rows from my pandas dataframe without iterating over the dataframe?

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
# make points and calculate distances
east=data['easting'].values
north=data['northing'].values
points=np.vstack((east,north)).T
distances=cdist(points,points) # big row x row matrix
zzzz=np.where(distances<0.5)

loc_dist=np.vstack((zzzz[0],zzzz[1])).T  #array of indices where points are
# to close together and will be filtered contains unwanted distance 
# comparisons such as comparing data[1,1] with data[1,1] which is always zero
#since it is the same point. also distance [1,2] is same as [2,1]

#My code for filtering the indices
loc_dist=loc_dist.astype('int') 
diff_loc=zzzz[0]-zzzz[1] # remove indices for comparing the same 
                         #point distance [n,n] = distance [n,n]
diff_zero=np.where(diff_loc==0)
loc_dist_s=np.delete(loc_dist, diff_zero[0],axis=0)
loc_find=np.unique(loc_dist_s) # remove indices for similar distance
                               #comparisons distance [n,m] = distance [m,n]
```

Comment: `df.drop(loc_find)` should work

Comment: @EdChum Thanks for the suggestion about loc_find this lead me to another question on Github that has the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @EdChum I found these two answered questions which work for me.

[A faster alternative to Pandas `isin` function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23945493/a-faster-alternative-to-pandas-isin-function)

[Select rows from a DataFrame based on values in a column in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-values-in-a-column-in-pandas)

Just needed to convert dataframe indexes to a column with

```
data.loc[:,'rindex1']=data.index.get_values()
```

and then to remove the rows use the following

```
data_df2=data.loc[~data['rindex1'].isin(loc_find)]
```

Hope this helps someone else.