# a faster way than the isin function of Pandas to extract conditional rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a very large knowledge graph in pandas dataframe format as follows.

This dataframe `KG` has more than 100 million rows.

KG:

```
                   pred     subj      obj
        0   nationality     BART      USA
        1  placeOfBirth     BART  NEWYORK
        2     locatedIn  NEWYORK      USA
      ...           ...      ...      ...
116390740     hasFather     BART   HOMMER
116390741   nationality   HOMMER      USA
116390743  placeOfBirth   HOMMER  NEWYORK
```

I tried to get a row from this KG with a specific value for subj.

Using the subj column as a series, I tried to indexing the KG by generating a boolean series using `isin()` function as shown below.

```
KG[KG['subj'].isin(['BART', 'NEWYORK'])]
```

My desired output is

```
                   pred     subj      obj
        0   nationality     BART      USA
        1  placeOfBirth     BART  NEWYORK
        2     locatedIn  NEWYORK      USA
116390740     hasFather     BART   HOMMER
```

I have to repeat the above

But the above method takes a long time. Is there any way to reduce the time effectively than this method?

thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A faster alternative to Pandas \`isin\` function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23945493/a-faster-alternative-to-pandas-isin-function)

Answer (score 1):

You can `set/sort index` and then pick the required values:
Looking up rows based on index values is faster than looking up rows based on column values. It's faster when the index is sorted.

```
df = df.set_index('subj')
df = df.sort_index()
result = df.loc[['BART', 'NEWYORK']]
```

You can try query after setting multiindex:

```
df = df.set_index(['subj','obj'])
df = df.sort_index()
df.query("subj in ['BART','NEWYORK'] & obj in ['USA','HOMMER']")
```

Comment: Is there any other way to deal with the following conditions?

`KG[KG['subj'].isin(['BART', 'NEWYORK']) & KG['obj'].isin(['USA', 'HOMMER'])]`