# Find closest value algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, search

```
def find_closest(data, target, key = lambda x:f(x))
```

This is my function definition where data is set of values, and I want to find the value that evaluates the closest to target in as **few** evaluations as possible, i.e. `abs(target-f(x))` is minimum. `f(x)` is monotonic.

I've heard that binary search can do this in O(log(n)) time, is there a library implementation in python? Are there more efficient search algorithms?

EDIT: I'm looking to minimize complexity in terms of evaluating f(x) because that's the expensive part. I want to find the x in data that when evaluated with f(x), comes closest to the target. `data` is in the domain of `f`, `target` is in the range of `f`. Yes, data can be sorted quickly.

Comment: You'll need `data` to be sorted to have O(log(n)) complexity. Describe `data` in your question

Comment: Did you mean `lambda x:f(x)`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the utilities in the [`bisect`](https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/bisect.html) module. You will have to evaluate `x` on `data` though, i.e. `list(f(x) for x in data)` to get a monotonic / sorted list to bisect.

I am not aware of a binary search in the standard library that works directly on `f` and `data`.

Answer (score 0):

If the data presented is already sorted and the function is strctly monotonic, 
apply the function `f` on the data and then perform a binary search using `bisect.bisect`

```
import bisect
def find_closest(data, target, key = f):

    data = map(f, data)
    if f(0) > f(1):
        data = [-e for e in data]
    try:
        return data[bisect.bisect_left(data, target)]
    except IndexError:
        return data[-1]
```

Comment: Finds first not greater than target, while closest is requested.

Comment: undefined f variable is used

Answer (score 0):

Use [`bisect_left()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/212358/binary-search-in-python) method to find lower bound.
`Bisect_left` accepts a random-access list of elements, to avoid calculating all of them you can use lazy collection of calculated function values with [`__len__`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/datamodel.html#object.__len__) and [`__getitem__`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__) methods defined.
Carefully check return value for border conditions.
Your heavy calculation will be called `O(log(N) + 1) = O(log(N))` times.

```
from bisect import bisect_left
from collections import defaultdict

class Cache(defaultdict):
    def __init__(self, method):
        self.method = method
    def __missing__(self, key):
        return self.method(key)

class MappedList(object):
    def __init__(self, method, input):
        self.method = method
        self.input = input
        self.cache = Cache(method)
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.input)
    def __getitem__(self, i):
        return self.cache[input[i]]

def find_closest(data, target, key = lambda x:x):
    s = sorted(data)
    evaluated = MappedList(key, s)
    index = bisect_left(evaluated, target)
    if index == 0:
        return data[0]
    if index == len(data):
        return data[index-1]
    if target - evaluated[index-1] <= evaluated[index] - target:
        return data[index-1]
    else:
        return data[index]
```

Comment: This looks good, didn't know that map was lazy. Here you're returning `f(x)`, right, instead of `x`. Just change it to `return data[index]`?

Comment: `imap` from your link doesn't support random access

Comment: [Check out mine](http://ideone.com/krSas4). Now with caching! :) Only two or three calculations for our 6-element input data.