# Random Choice is out of list range in Python?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, random

I am trying to create a program that will guess the number you entered. I was trying to get the computer to get the number in as few guesses as possible so I am doing something like a binary search. I keep getting a Index out of range when I run the code and it gets to `total = total[the_low_one:computer2_guess]`. I am confused why it is out of range. Should I be adding or subtracting one to `the_low_one` each time it hits a new low so it stays in range? I would appreciate any help as I am lost. Thanks a bunch in advance!
Code:

```
def second_computer():
    global computer2_score
    computer2_score=0
    computer2_guess= -1
    the_low_one=1
    the_high_one=1000000
    total= range(1,1000000)
    while computer2_guess != pick_number:
        computer2_guess=random.choice(total)
        if computer2_guess>pick_number:
            total=total[the_low_one:computer2_guess]
            the_high_one=computer2_guess-1
        else:
            total=total[computer2_guess:the_high_one]
            the_low_one=computer2_guess+1
        computer2_score+=1
```

Comment: Your formatting needs a bit work -- but I think your problem is you initialize `the_low_one` to 1 instead of 0.

Comment: What do you mean by formatting? .

Comment: Your indentation after the `while` statement needs to be fixed

Comment: Oh, sorry I didn't realize it didn't indent properly online. Thanks for noticing! I tried changing it to 0 but the same error happened.

Comment: You have a number of logic errors. Your slices are using values from the total[] array, rather than indicies. And where is pick_number defined?

Comment: What could I do to change it?

Comment: I'm curious -- why did you not use a simple binary search? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/212358/binary-search-in-python

Comment: I can't really figure out how to set it up and make it work. I think my program would work fine if I could figure out how to get rid of the Index Error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `total` shrinks, the numerical values in the list no longer line up with their indices. You could make it work by doing

`total=total[total.index(the_low_one):total.index(the_high_one)]`

A simpler approach would be to do away with `total` altogether and set
`computer2_guess=random.randint(the_low_one,the_high_one)`

Comment: I don't know why I didn't just do the `randint`in the first place. Thanks!

Comment: what happens if randint is 1000000?